# Convert JSON format to CSV format for MS Excel

Tags: json

I received a JSON file but don't know how to read it. Is there a converter where I can produce a nice CSV file so it can be loaded into MS Excel? I don't understand JSON, so it would be awesome if someone wrote a script or link me to one that would do the job.

I found something close at http://json.bloople.net but, unfortunately, it's JSON to HTML.

Edit: jsonformat.com gets even closer, however it's still not CSV.

Comment: there is a reason. CSV is not hierachical/structured/wellformed, JSON/HTML/XML is. do you just want to get a massive string? (not caring about the ordering)?

Comment: I just need something that can be read on a table format, I thought using CSV was the right way since I can just open it up on Excel and start editing the data.

Comment: it is worth noting that not all JSON can reliably be converted to CSV. Here are some examples of JSON that could not: http://json.org/example.html It sounds like the structure of the JSON you're doing with is relatively simple, however.

Comment: [json-csv.com](https://json-csv.com) converts JSON to CSV online

Comment: this app can be used https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/json-into-spreadsheet/9nvgjblt01mt

Comment: https://transform-x.dev/json-to-excel is a web ui that can do this, but you need to have the JSON in the right format.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're doing, but this will go from JSON to CSV using JavaScript.  This is using the [open source JSON library](http://www.json.org/js.html), so just download JSON.js into the same folder you saved the code below into, and it will parse the static JSON value in `json3` into CSV and prompt you to download/open in Excel.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>JSON to CSV</title>
    <script src="scripts/json.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var json3 = { "d": "[{\"Id\":1,\"UserName\":\"Sam Smith\"},{\"Id\":2,\"UserName\":\"Fred Frankly\"},{\"Id\":1,\"UserName\":\"Zachary Zupers\"}]" }

    DownloadJSON2CSV(json3.d);

    function DownloadJSON2CSV(objArray)
    {
        var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;

        var str = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            var line = '';

            for (var index in array[i]) {
                line += array[i][index] + ',';
            }

            // Here is an example where you would wrap the values in double quotes
            // for (var index in array[i]) {
            //    line += '"' + array[i][index] + '",';
            // }

            line.slice(0,line.Length-1); 

            str += line + '\r\n';
        }
        window.open( "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(str))
    }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>This page does nothing....</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, not really a programmer here... how do I 'use' this?

Comment: Sorry... please bear with me... which program do I paste this code into? Does it have to be in the same directory as the JSON files?

Comment: This is javascript, you can just paste this into a web page and use it to convert JSON to CSV...  If you want it to save into a file, you can replace "return str;" with "window.open( "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(str);".

Comment: The above code does not seem to handle the case where json value has "," in it. eg."Sam, Smith".  Maybe someone could confirm this.

Comment: If you want to support embedded comma's like "Sam, Smith", you'll need to embed quotes around the value.

Comment: @Zachary what if the json is a lil bit complex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257062/converting-json-object-to-csv-format-in-javascript

Comment: @Zachary to ensure that resulting CSV is valid, one should also escape quotes if one of the values happens to contain some

Comment: Probably makes sense to use a javascript CSV library like http://agnes.codeplex.com/ or https://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/ than to roll your own CSV writing script.

Comment: Wow, that "window.open( "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(str))" line, it's the healing. I was looking for something to do this and gave up and now, I'm ungiving up.

Comment: @Zachary, this is good! The file is always .part, have you a solution to that?

Comment: The line window.open( "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(str)) throws a Uncaught TypeError in Chrome.  is says Property 'open' of object [object global] is not a function.  Does anyone have a fix for this or know why it is happening?

Comment: @Zachary hi, using this example the output file is just download, how can i change this? it wont be a .csv file

Comment: This works for me, but when I have special characters like Č,Ć,Š it doesn't work. I get something like "%u017D" instead of them. Do you have any idea how to make this code to works with special characters?  Thanks.

Answer (score 67):

I created a JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sturtevant/vUnF9/) based on [the answer given by Zachary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4130939/317). It provides a more accessible user interface and also escapes double quotes within strings properly.

Comment: I forked it to support missing key-value pairs http://jsfiddle.net/gonzif/MfJPF/1/ Your first JSON object is used to define the column keys.

Comment: those are cool, but neither support json arrays. so it doesn't handle [
 {
  "Id":1,
  "UserName":"Sam Smith",
  "Details":{
   "hair":"red",
   "eyes":"red"
  }
 }]

Comment: Also, when I click download then that start downloading with filename "download" so there has no extension of the file. So Would you please let me know how I can rename the file.

Comment: It didn't work for me

Comment: When clicked on download in the fiddle, it doesn't download with a proper extension (.csv). Could you please help on what change needs to be done ?

Answer (score 1):

Using Python will be one easy way to achieve what you want.

I found one using Google.

"[convert from json to csv using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/convert-from-json-to-csv-using-python)" is an example.

Comment: I have never used Python before, I only know that its a programming language, any alternatives?

Comment: You mentioned earlier that you could convert JSON to HTML. Excel is able to open HTML. Have you tried that?

Comment: The following [EE Article](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/Perl/A_10413-Using-Perl-to-preview-in-a-Web-Page-and-convert-a-JSON-document-into-an-Excel-workbook.html) is Perl based, but may give you a few ideas, as it will hapily display a JSON file as a Dojo based Grid, or convert it to XLS or XLSX.  There's also a Java based solution [json2excel](http://sourceforge.net/projects/json2excel/) vvailable on sourceforge.

Answer (score 1):

You can use that gist, pretty easy to use, stores your settings in local storage: https://gist.github.com/4533361

Comment: I don't understand what you want me to type in the boxes "header", "extract items", or "Convert item", nor what you want me to change in the source code.