# Issue when converting from HTML to text using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have the following code snippet to convert html to javascript, but I seem to be facing an issue with the output when bound to a textarea and I am not able to figure out what the issue could be.

```
var html_to_text = $('#source').val().replace('&nbsp;', ' ').replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '').replace(/(<br>)+/g, '<br>');
```

The output is correct when displaying on an alert, but, when the same is bound to a text area,  there is a lot of white space on it. Could someone help me understand what could be the issue with the above snippet.

I have a working sample of the same at http://jsfiddle.net/technicaliti/uuxDx/

Comment: What's the problem? You have a lot of whitespace (`\n` and spaces) in your original HTML, and you're removing a lot of non-whitespace. Which leaves...a lot of whitespace. Also, your first `.replace()` call doesn't use a Regular Expression, so it's only going to replace the first occurrence of a (nonexistent) `&nbsp;`

Comment: How does it show the correct output on the alert and not on the #destination textarea. Am i missing something?

Comment: I see a lot of whitespace in both the alert and the textarea.

Comment: Do you need to add .replace(/\s{2,}/g, '\n\r') to the chain?

Comment: `$('#source').val().replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '').replace(/\n/g, '');`

Comment: @rps, that still keeps the &nbsp; as is. @Ian, I have change the nbsp; replace to `.replace(/[&]nbsp[;]/gi," ")`. Hope this is good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add .replace(/\s{2,}/g, '\n\r') to the end.

Comment: 1>the correct order is `\r\n` **not** `\n\r` 2>that would replace whitespace,\r,\f to newline

Comment: This answer works correctly without loosing the format and with the improvement suggested by @Anirudh.

Answer (score 0):

`.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g,"");`

This one removes only multiple newlines (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10805292/2049063)) so you still get a nice format

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uuxDx/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the line break with nothing.

```
        html_to_text = html_to_text.replace(/\n/g, '');
```