# remove a carriage return or newline from JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working with an array populated by a text file and parsed with a regex. The first element in my array appears with either \r or \n like so:

"
This is the first element"

This only occurs on the first element. How would I go about removing this hidden character? I have tried  map with replace('\r', ''), and other iterations of replace with no luck. Thanks for any help.

Comment: you would have to escape the backslash.
Try `replace('\\r', '')` or even use regex like `replace(/\\r?\\n/g,'')`

Comment: This looks like you're trying to treat a symptom and not the cause; track down where this char is coming from.

Comment: Replace seems to work fine.. `"\rtest".charCodeAt(0)--=13` `"\rtest".replace('\r','').charCodeAt(0)--=116`

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much more than replace, really. To remove all those characters you can use:

```
str.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '');
```

**Mind you** have to re-assign the result to the string as it is not an in-place replace but it creates a copy of the string:

```
str = str.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '');
```

I would discourage using a regular expression for such a simple task. It would be overkill and take much more processing time. I admit it's a tiny fraction of time, but in a massive loop it may make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Tried adding as a comment but a previously answered question should get you going in the right direction.

[How to remove all line breaks from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805125/how-to-remove-all-line-breaks-from-a-string)