# Removing invisible characters from the end of a Java String

Tags: java, string

how can i find the last visible character in a Java String? I'd like to remove all line breaks and other invisible characters from a Java String

Kind Regards,
Tord

Comment: use a regex expression

Comment: Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805125/how-to-remove-all-line-breaks-from-a-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) method of the `String` class for removing trailing (and leading) white space and line breaks:

```
String trimmed = original.trim();
```

Comment: trim does not remove '\u200B' (zero width space). which is the problem I was having. Using .replaceAll("\\p{C}", "?") from the more upvoted answer worked for me

Answer (score 13):

```
string_variable.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "?");
```

This will replace all non-printable characters. Where p{C} selects the invisible control characters and unused code points.

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately this will remove all characters, i'm trying to find the last visible character in an article (like maybe a period or a letter or a number). Then i can remove the rest of the characters that are coming after that