# General method to trim non-printable characters in Clojure

Tags: string, clojure, trim, string-matching, zero-width-space

I encountered a bug where I couldn't match two seemingly 'identical' strings together. For example, the following two strings fail to match:
"sample" and "​sample".

To replicate the issue, one can run the following in Clojure.

```
(= "sample" "​sample") ; returns false
```

After an hour of frustrated debugging, I discovered that there was a **zero-width space** at the front of the second string! Removing it from this particular example via a backspace is trivial. However I have a database of strings that I'm matching, and it seems like there are multiple strings facing this issue. My question is: **is there a general method to trim zero-width spaces in Clojure?**

Some method's I've tried:

```
(count (clojure.string/trim "​abc")) ; returns 4
```

```
(count (clojure.string/replace "​abc" #"\s" "")) ; returns 4
```

This thread [Remove zero-width space characters from a JavaScript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305797/remove-zero-width-space-characters-from-a-javascript-string) does provide a solution with regular expressions that works in this example, i.e.

```
(count (clojure.string/replace "​abc" #"[\u200B-\u200D\uFEFF]" "")) ; returns 3
```

However, as stated in the post itself, there are many other potential ascii characters that may be invisible. So I'm still interested if there's a more general method that doesn't rely on listing all possible invisible unicode symbols.

Comment: I'm not aware of a built-in function in Clojure that does what you want. I just read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space to be more familiar with 0 width characters. To solve your issue, unfortunately, I think you should maintain manually a list of characters to trim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe, what you are referring to are so-called *non-printable characters*. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32685095/1008794) in Java, you could pass the `#"\p{C}"` regular expression as pattern to `replace`:

```
(defn remove-non-printable-characters [x]
  (clojure.string/replace x #"\p{C}" ""))
```

However, this will remove line breaks, e.g. `\n`. So in order to keep those characters, we need a more complex regular expression:

```
(defn remove-non-printable-characters [x]
  (clojure.string/replace x #"[\p{C}&&^(\S)]" ""))
```

This function will remove non-printable characters. Let's test it:

```
(= "sample" "​sample")
;; => false

(= (remove-non-printable-characters "sample")
   (remove-non-printable-characters "​sample"))
;; => true

(remove-non-printable-characters "sam\nple")
;; => "sam\nple"
```

The `\p{C}` pattern is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44034552/1008794).

Comment: Very nice, thank you :) Also useful to note that this method removes control characters including '\n', but leaves normal spaces ` ` unaffected.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out! Didn't notice. I will see if I can improve the answer a bit regarding that.

Answer (score 1):

The regex solution from @Rulle is very nice.  The [tupelo.chars](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.214/api/tupelo.chars) namespace also has a collection of character classes and predicate functions that could be useful.  They work in Clojure and ClojureScript, and also include the `^nbsp;` for browsers.  In particular, check out the [visible?](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.214/api/tupelo.chars#visible?) predicate.

The [tupelo.string](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.214/api/tupelo.string) namespace also has a number of helper & convenience functions for string processing.

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.chars :as chars]
    [tupelo.string :as str] ))

(def sss
"Some multi-line
string." )

(dotest
  (println "result:")
  (println
    (str/join
      (filterv
        #(or (chars/visible? %) 
             (chars/whitespace? %))
        sss))))
```

with result

```
result:
Some multi-line
string.
```

To use, make your `project.clj` look like:

```
  :dependencies [
                 [org.clojure/clojure "1.10.2-alpha1"]
                 [prismatic/schema "1.1.12"]
                 [tupelo "20.07.01"]
                 ]
```