# Comparing two identical strings in JQuery returns false

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I discovered an interesting problem with an echoed value from an AJAX request of JQuery, which I don't have an answere for:

My `data == "LOCKED"` never returns true (line 13)!

**JQuery** -> AJAX call on button-click:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "ajax/login_ajax_call.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: { user: usr, password: pwd }
    }).done(function(data){
            if(data == true || data == "true"){          // -> this works with data beeing true (bool) or "true" (string)
                $("#form_submit").submit();
            }
            else{
                console.log(jQuery.type(data));          // -> (string)
                console.log(data);                       // -> "LOCKED" 
                console.log(jQuery.type("LOCKED"));      // -> (string)
                if(data == "LOCKED"){                    // also tried "===" but it never returns true
                    [...]            
                }
                else{
                    [...]
                }
            }
    }); 
});
```

**PHP**(1) -> gets a value returned by a Class(PHP(2)):

```
include_once("../Classes/Login_check.php");
$lih = new Login_check();
$result = $lih -> check($_POST["user"], $_POST["password"]);
var_dump($result);                                     // -> string(6) "LOCKED"
echo $result;
```

**PHP**(2, "Login_check.php"):

```
[...]
// also tried: 
// $test = "LOCKED"; 
// var_dump($test);                                    // -> string(6) "LOCKED"
// return $test;
return "LOCKED";
[...]
```

Tell me if you need further informations!
I hope anyone know what causes this problem!

Comment: Have you tried `trim()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Must be because of some white-spaces or new lines, it is always better to trim the `data`. Try this:

```
if (data.trim() == "LOCKED") {
```

You can also use:

```
if ($.trim(data) == "LOCKED") { // using jQuery.
```

Comment: Tried both, still returns false.

Comment: @Y.Hermes Can you kindly tell the value of `console.log(encodeURIComponent(data));` please?

Comment: Dont know what this means :D
%0D%0Astring(6)%20%22LOCKED%22%0ALOCKED

Comment: Wow... You have got something else is also returning. Man!!! You are returning as `"LOCKED"`. Yo!! You need to compare with `'"LOCKED"'`. LoL.

Comment: @Y.Hermes Kindly show a screenshot and put it in your post. Looks like you are outputting something crazy. `:)`

Comment: @Y.Hermes First, remove the `var_dump()`. Then put the `console.log()`.

Comment: Well i know that var_dump() is also returning. This was just for testing reasons. But you are right that i forgot to remove it before testing your console.log. :'D Now it returns     %0D%0ALOCKED

Comment: @Y.Hermes `%0D%0A` is a new line I guess. Although I don't understand why it follows `%0D`. Let's see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100479/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-y-hermes).

Comment: @Y.Hermes `%0d` is the carriage return character, and `%0a` is the linefeed character. This is generated by Windows Servers.

Comment: @Y.Hermes After removing the `var_dump()` and other things, I am definitely sure this should work now. Kindly check.

Comment: Bad that im using an Ubuntu ;) Translatedwith @Rajesh 's help it means "\r\nLOCKED"

Comment: ^^^ Rightly said... It is CR LF. `:)` I don't know why Ubuntu is generating CRLF.

Comment: Not yet, but i'm still trying^^ Quick and dirty there would be an easy resolution by just deleting "\r\n" but thats not my intention of reworking and optimizing my page, LOL :D But why the hell is "\r\n" beeing added by Ubuntu/phpmyadmin/whatever on an echo?

Comment: @Y.Hermes Show us your full PHP Code? PasteBin or something will also be okay! `:)` Make sure you don't have an extra line, before or after `<?php ?>`

Comment: @Y.Hermes Kindly check if you have some whitespaces before and after `<?php ?>` and remove them off.

Comment: Nope. :/ Checked completly

Comment: @Y.Hermes Remove all the `var_dump`, debugger cr@p, and clean the PHP script. Now what does `console.log(encodeURIComponent(data))` say? And also what does `console.log(encodeURIComponent(trim(data)))` say?

Comment: After correctiong your 

console.log(encodeURIComponent(trim(data))) 

to

console.log(encodeURIComponent($.trim(data)))

the result is:

%0D%0ALOCKED

and

LOCKED

Comment: So:
if(encodeURIComponent($.trim(data)) == "LOCKED") was the correct answere.

Comment: You don't need the `encodeURIComponent()` there. `:)`

Comment: getting false even 2 strings are same in jquery

typeof(item.pcp_name)
"string"
typeof(searchdata)
"string"
item.pcp_name.localeCompare(searchdata)
1
$.trim(item.pcp_name)==$.trim(searchdata)
false
searchdata
"LEMERY, ROBERT"
item.pcp_name
"LEMERY, ROBERT"

Comment: @Bhanupratap Can you ask a question and add necessary details, I'll be able to help... `:)`

Answer (score 2):

You can try `JSON.parse`. If value looks like `"LOCKED"` on console, it means its like `""LOCKED""`.

#### Edit 1

As commented, you are getting `"\r\nLOCKED"` as stringified value, so you can use a regex to replace it. Following is the updated code.

[Reference - How to remove all line breaks from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805125/how-to-remove-all-line-breaks-from-a-string)

#### Sample

```js
var a = "LOCKED";
var strA = "\r\nLOCKED";
var regex = /\r?\n|\r/g;
var cleanStr = strA.replace(regex,'');
console.log(a);
console.log(strA);

console.log(strA == a);
console.log(cleanStr == a);
```

Comment: Gets me a way nearer to the result: With a stringify it returns: "\r\nLOCKED"

Comment: Would get a second +1 from me but, you are right, it is solving the problem (but, that results out of another probleme). If I won't find the first mistake, i'll accept that answere, thanks a lot!

Comment: Ideally you should find why are you receiving such result from server and send it in proper format.

Answer (score 1):

Probably due to whitepace somewhere, such as a space before an opening php tag etc.

Far better to use a structured data format like json, and return a boolean propery to avoid these issues:

```
$result = $lih -> check($_POST["user"], $_POST["password"]);
$locked = ($result == 'LOCKED');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(['locked'=>$locked]);
```

Javascript:

```
if(data.locked){
```