# how to convert text file to json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a text file like the one below

```
id      nm              lat         lon         countryCode
819827  Razvilka        55.591667   37.740833   RU
524901  Moscow          55.752220   37.615555   RU
1271881 Firozpur        27.799999   76.949997   IN
```

i need to to convert to json like the format below

```
[{"id":819827,"nm":"Razvilka","lat":55.591667,"lon":37.740833,"countryCode":"RU"},
{"id":524901,"nm":"Moscow","lat":55.752220,"lon":37.615555,"countryCode":"RU"},
{"id":1271881,"nm":"Firozpur","lat":27.799999,"lon":76.949997,"countryCode":"IN"}]
```

for a javascript application.

```
myapp.controller('TCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('list.txt').success(function(data) {
    $scope.todos = JSON.parse(data);
    //console.log(data)
  });
}]);
```

Comment: hey lxe , i have added the piece of code i have had

Comment: There isn't a standard way to do what you want, but you can use a csv parsing library, like this one: http://papaparse.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) Get an array of cells by splitting the string on the carriage return (rows), then using `map` to return an new array based on the row split on the spaces.

```
var cells = str.split('\n').map(function (el) { return el.split(/\s+/); });
```

2) Headings are the first nested array in `cells`.

```
var headings = cells.shift();
```

3) `map` over the cells building and returning a new object based on the values.

```
var obj = cells.map(function (el) {
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 0, l = el.length; i < l; i++) {
    obj[headings[i]] = isNaN(Number(el[i])) ? el[i] : +el[i];
  }
  return obj;
});
```

4) Stringify the returned object.

```
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

OUTPUT

```
[
  {
    "id": 819827,
    "nm": "Razvilka",
    "lat": 55.591667,
    "lon": 37.740833,
    "countryCode": "RU"
  },
  {
    "id": 524901,
    "nm": "Moscow",
    "lat": 55.75222,
    "lon": 37.615555,
    "countryCode": "RU"
  },
  {
    "id": 1271881,
    "nm": "Firozpur",
    "lat": 27.799999,
    "lon": 76.949997,
    "countryCode": "IN"
  }
]
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1ppcwmut/)

Comment: My input happens to also have \r\n which this doesn't account for. Any idea how to handle this?

Comment: You can use a regex in the split. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805125/how-to-remove-all-line-breaks-from-a-string

Comment: Your solution works great, thank you! But I have a problem with empty lines (e.g. on the end of an exported txt-file). How do I achieve this to remove or skip any empty lines within your code?