# Parse from provided data using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I got a txt data source as below, anyone could suggest a way to parse to Json so I could use on my purpose, please. I want to use data to create a chart 
[txt file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1__GDoXnTkcdNPvxwjL-HX-Dc5EEHTd-S/view?usp=sharing)

```
Sales Summary on *Tue Feb 11 2020*
Orders: *2345* [Delivery: 1470 CarryOut: 2977] - [Success: 3746 Failed: 5]
Total: $63456.81
[0800: 288 Web: 6783 iOS: 223 Android: 981]
Store A A: Orders 51 - Total: 1548.67
    0800: Order: 0 [Delivery: 0 CarryOut: 0] [Success: 0 Failed: 0]
    Web: Order: 42 [Delivery: 21 CarryOut: 21] [Success: 2 Failed: 0]
    iOS: Order: 5 [Delivery: 4 CarryOut: 1] [Success: 5 Failed: 0]
    Android: Order: 4 [Delivery: 1 CarryOut: 3] [Success: 4 Failed: 0]
Store B: Orders 53 - Total: 1351.62
    0800: Order: 1 [Delivery: 1 CarryOut: 0] [Success: 1 Failed: 0]
    Web: Order: 41 [Delivery: 7 CarryOut: 34] [Success: 11 Failed: 0]
    iOS: Order: 6 [Delivery: 0 CarryOut: 6] [Success: 6 Failed: 0]
    Android: Order: 5 [Delivery: 1 CarryOut: 4] [Success: 5 Failed: 0]
Store C C: Orders 45 - Total: 1390.78
    0800: Order: 4 [Delivery: 0 CarryOut: 4] [Success: 4 Failed: 0]
    Web: Order: 33 [Delivery: 11 CarryOut: 22] [Success: 56 Failed: 0]
    iOS: Order: 3 [Delivery: 1 CarryOut: 2] [Success: 3 Failed: 0]
    Android: Order: 5 [Delivery: 0 CarryOut: 5] [Success: 5 Failed: 0]
Store D: Orders 27 - Total: 671.14
    0800: Order: 0 [Delivery: 0 CarryOut: 0] [Success: 0 Failed: 0]
    Web: Order: 19 [Delivery: 6 CarryOut: 13] [Success: 19 Failed: 0]
    iOS: Order: 7 [Delivery: 2 CarryOut: 5] [Success: 7 Failed: 0]
    Android: Order: 1 [Delivery: 0 CarryOut: 1] [Success: 1 Failed: 0]
Store E E E: Orders 52 - Total: 1196.97
    0800: Order: 1 [Delivery: 1 CarryOut: 0] [Success: 1 Failed: 0]
    Web: Order: 39 [Delivery: 7 CarryOut: 32] [Success: 22 Failed: 8]
    iOS: Order: 8 [Delivery: 2 CarryOut: 6] [Success: 8 Failed: 0]
    Android: Order: 4 [Delivery: 0 CarryOut: 4] [Success: 4 Failed: 0]
```

Comment: Is this purely saved as a txt file with given format?

Comment: I have updated the link to txt file. That is purely txt without format. So I want to make it formattable then I can extract data from that to create a chart

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36120265/how-to-convert-text-file-to-json-in-javascript