# Append Multi line to a single line string

Tags: javascript, replace

I have this type of string in a text file:

> First line
> Second line
>
> other line
> another line
>
> more line
> next line

How can I append all the string into a single line ?

the required output is :

> First line second line other line another line more line next line

I had try removing white space and append string tutorial but still did not get the required output.

Comment: What language are you working on?

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805125/how-to-remove-all-line-breaks-from-a-string . You need to remove line breaks from your string.

Answer (score 1):

you could replace new line characters with a space:

```js
console.log(txt.value.replace(/[\n\r]/g, ' '));
```

```html
<textarea id="txt">
First line Second line

other line another line

more line next line
</textarea>
```