# Javascript Split and trim delineator

Tags: javascript, split

I have a 10 million line text file loaded stored as a string in a variable "someString".  I want to generate an array where each line is an item.  I know that to do that I would do the following:

```
var files = someString.split("\n");
```

However, this keeps the line break symbol \n after each item.  What is the *most efficient* way to trim this from each item?

Comment: Chances are the data is in `CRLF` format (typical for Windows text). You're splitting on `LF` (`\n`) but the `CR` (`\r`) is still present

Comment: 10M lines is a lot of data to handle in JS. You might be better off with something that can stream the data instead of loading it all into memory

Answer (score 2):

Try using a regex delimiter to handle different line-ending characters for Windows (`\r\n`) and others (`\n` **or** `\r`)

```
someString.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/)
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this answer on [How to remove all line breaks from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805125/how-to-remove-all-line-breaks-from-a-string).

someText = someText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");

Comment: OP wants an array of strings, not a single string with all end-of-line characters removed