# Unexpected quoted property in dynamically created object

Tags: javascript

I try to load contents of the CSV file into the array of JavaScript objects. Unfortunately, structure of data is not flat, so to mitigate that, I use dot-separated property names as column headers in CSV file. Example CSV file looks as follows:

```
codes.code1,codes.code2,codes.code3,codes.code4,info.description.text,info.description.language
49074202,64,1443,1416,Test description: 49074202 64 1443 1416,EN
81905948,10,9721,5411,Test description: 81905948 10 9721 5411,EN
87262350,86,7050,4775,Test description: 87262350 86 7050 4775,EN
```

The object structure I would like to end up with looks like

```
{
    codes: {
        code1: "49074202",
        code2: "64",
        code3: "1443",
        code4: "1416"
    },
    info: {
        description: {
            text: "Test description: 49074202 64 1443 1416",
            language: "EN"
        }
    }
}
```

Following code can be used to recreate the problem (using CSV file with contents posted above).

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="file" id="files" onchange="loadFromFile()" />
            <script>
                function loadFromFile() {
                    var selectedFile = document.getElementById('files').files[0];
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = loadRowsFromFile;
                    reader.readAsText(selectedFile);
                };

                function loadRowsFromFile(e) {
                    var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
                    if (!rows || rows.length === 0) {
                        return;
                    }
                    var headers = rows[0].split(",");

                    var loadedData = [];
                    for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        var columns = rows[i].split(",");

                        var rowData = {};
                        for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                            placeElementInHierarchy(rowData, headers[j], columns[j]);
                        }
                        loadedData.push(rowData);
                    }
                    console.log(loadedData);
                }

                function placeElementInHierarchy(rowData, propertyPath, value) {
                    var path = propertyPath.split(".");
                    var obj = rowData;
                    for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
                        if (i === path.length - 1) {
                            obj[path[i]] = value;
                        } else {
                            if (!obj[path[i]]) {
                                obj[path[i]] = {};
                            }
                            obj = obj[path[i]];
                        }
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

File parsing works properly, data is loaded correctly into the structure. However, for some reason the last processed property name is quoted. Structure of all rows I obtain looks like that:

```
{
    codes: {
        code1: "49074202",
        code2: "64",
        code3: "1443",
        code4: "1416"
    },
    info: {
        description:{
            text: "Test description: 49074202 64 1443 1416",
            "language": "EN"
        }
    }
}
```

The only lead I have right now is that if I remove the 'language' column from CSV file, then 'text' is being quoted instead - so the last processed property is for some reason quoted. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Fixed mistakes in the expected structure.

**EDIT2:** What is interesting, following code (skipping file upload part), doesn't show such symptoms

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <script>                


                (function() {
                    var csvData = 'codes.code1,codes.code2,codes.code3,codes.code4,info.description.text,info.description.language\n' +
                                '49074202,64,1443,1416,Test description: 49074202 64 1443 1416,EN\n' +
                                '81905948,10,9721,5411,Test description: 81905948 10 9721 5411,EN\n' +
                                '87262350,86,7050,4775,Test description: 87262350 86 7050 4775,EN';
                    loadRowsFromFile(csvData);
                })();



                function loadRowsFromFile(csvData) {
                    var rows = csvData.split("\n");
                    if (!rows || rows.length === 0) {
                        return;
                    }
                    var headers = rows[0].split(",");

                    var loadedData = [];
                    for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        var columns = rows[i].split(",");

                        var rowData = {};
                        for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                            placeElementInHierarchy(rowData, headers[j], columns[j]);
                        }
                        loadedData.push(rowData);
                    }
                    console.log(loadedData);
                }

                function placeElementInHierarchy(rowData, propertyPath, value) {
                    var path = propertyPath.split(".");
                    var obj = rowData;
                    for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
                        if (i === path.length - 1) {
                            obj[path[i]] = value;
                        } else {
                            if (!obj[path[i]]) {
                                obj[path[i]] = {};
                            }
                            obj = obj[path[i]];
                        }
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The quotes are not introduced by your code.

Comment: Also it's not clear how the "info" column headers would generate the structure you posted. You've got `info.description.text` and `info.description.language`, so it seems like you should end up with an "info" property that has a single "description" property, which in turn has two properties, "text" and "language".

Comment: Anyway the quotes don't matter. Add `console.log(loadedData[0].info.description.language)` and you'll get "EN" I predict.

Comment: Fixed mistakes in expected output - sorry for that. Quotes seem to make a difference, when I later try to access this data using Angular directives.

Comment: I think the quotes are an artifact introduced by `console.log()`. Try it in a different browser.

Comment: This is not related to console.log(). Tested using development tools in Firefox & Chrome, as well as actual production code that depends on this script. Problem is with the internal structure of produced JS objects.

Comment: The thing is, there are no `"` characters introduced anywhere by your code.

Comment: Well, this is pretty much what this question is about - where these quotations come from?

Comment: Can you please put together a [mcve], maybe using Stack Snippets (icon in editor looks like `<>`)? You'll likely want to store the CSV in a variable and change your code accordingly.

Comment: With very minor changes (basically as @MikeMcCaughan described), your code works perfectly well when I run it in Node. One thing I notice is that your `loadRowsFromFile()` function does not include a `return` statement, so it ultimately does not really do anything useful. How exactly did you conclude that the mysterious quotes are causing the actual problem you're experiencing?

Comment: I've extracted the upload part from the larger project to decrease amount of code. Normally loadRowsFromFile stores the results in one of controller's properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Okay. As you can see in screen above, your problem is generated by Carriage Return character `\r` on end of every line in the file. You can remove all your empty characters from string using

```
trim()
```

or you can use regexp to cut out just this type of characters. 
Example is done here:
[How to remove all line breaks from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805125/how-to-remove-all-line-breaks-from-a-string)