# wrap multiple lines starting and ending with " with line breaks in between them in notepad++ with REGEX

Tags: regex, notepad++

Basically i am looking to merge the lines starting and ending quotes

`The dog is barking
 "The sky
  is
blue"`

I am looking for an output shown below

```
The dog is barking
The sky is blue
```

Comment: There are many ways to remove line breaks.  Which programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using notepad++ and looking for a regex to find and replace all these blank spaces

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know much about REGEX but I have edited your question to be more visible to those who are.  I did find a post that you might be able to adapt to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805125/how-to-remove-all-line-breaks-from-a-string

Comment: Can you use any external tool for it? Are you on Windows or Linux? Do you have just one file or more than one?

Comment: i am on windows and have just one file

Answer (score 0):

Regex: /(\r?\n)/

\r (optional) : carriage return (windows) 
\n            : line feed

Comment: Thank you. I need to pick lines starting only with quotes " and ending with " and process them to a single line .I started with ^" but unble to pick all the blanks to end with the ".

Comment: Why are you putting slashes arround the regex?