# How to remove line breaks from a string, but only between certain tags?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have already found [How to remove all line breaks from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10805125/1066234) but instead of a simple string I have HTML tags within. My goal is to remove all line breaks only for the string parts that are **within** `<p>` tags.

Example String:

```
var str = `<h1>Headline do not touch me, nor the line break</h1>

<p>This is 
a test string, please 
put me on one line.</p>`;
```

Should become:

```
var str = `<h1>Headline do not touch me, nor the line break</h1>

<p>This is a test string, please put me on one line.</p>`;
```

What would be the JS code / Regex to achieve this?

Note: There are several p tags in my strings in production.

I found this on another website but are not able to modify it accordingly:
`str=str.replace(/(<[^>]+>)/g,function(w){return w.replace(/(\r\n|[\r\n])/g,' ')});`

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just get text of tag? `element.innerText`

Comment: Background is that I am getting random strings (containing HTML) and read it out using Google Speech engine. So no, I cannot control the incoming content of strings. (Line breaks cause the engine to make a break.)

Comment: Does Google Speech somehow differently reads new lines in text?

Comment: Using the API it obviously does a pause for each new line. Otherwise I would not have to ask this question :)

Comment: in your desired result you want `</h1><p>` or `</h1>\n<p>` ?

Comment: `</h1>\n<p>` because I strip the tags later on. So headline should be on one line and the content of the paragraph on the next line. Thanks for pointing this out. I added the desired result to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two regex one to replace new line inside tags and another to remove between tags

1. `<[^>]+>[\s\S]+?<\/[^>]+>`  `--> to remove new line inside tags`

[image]

2. `(<\/[^>]+>)\n+(?=<[^>]+>)` `--> to remove new line between tags`

[image]

```js
let str = `<h1>Headline
One Do not touch</h1>



<p>
This is 
a test string, please 
put me on one line.
</p>

<p>

some text
</p>
`

let output = str.replace(/<[^>]+>[\s\S]+?<\/[^>]+>/g, m => m.replace(/\n+/g, ''))

let final = output.replace(/(<\/[^>]+>)\n+(?=<[^>]+>)/g,'$1\n')
console.log(final)
```

Comment: Looks complicated but works :) Thanks. Any way to reduce it to <p> tags only?

Comment: You can change regex to specific to `<p>` tag only by using `<p>` instead of `<[^>]+>` and `<\/p>` instead of  `<\/[^>]+>`

Answer (score 0):

Below code works if you have only one p tag in your string.

```
var str = `<h1>Headline do not touch me, nor the line break</h1>

<p>
This is 
a test string, please 
put me on one line.
</p>`;

var str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('<p>')) + str.slice(str.indexOf('<p>'), str.indexOf('</p>')).replace(/(\r\n|[\r\n])/g,' ') + str.substring(str.indexOf('</p>'), str.length);
```

Comment: Thanks, however, unfortunately there are a bunch of p tags. That's why I have asked for the regex.