# Why is my string comparison in fetch response not working properly?

Tags: javascript, fetch, string-comparison

Basically, I am posting id of draft to server to delete draft using fetch and server will response with success text if it succeeds. Here is my code.

```
fetch(this.url + "/vue/api/processdraft?action=delete&id=" + item.id, {
    method: "POST"
})
    .then(response => {
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response === "success") {
            console.log("Test");
            this.draftList.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });
```

In above code, in console.log(response) shows ***success*** as expected. But code inside if block doesn't work. And I cannot figure out what is wrong with it? It won't even print ***Test*** as it is supposed to.
Here is screenshot of output.

[image]

And I've also checked that there is no white space before or after response text if it matters.

**Edit:** I checked for whitespaces in serverside and although I made sure there were no whitespace, but forgot to consider newline character. So this've been solved using trim() as suggested by answers.

Comment: Is there a space in there? Or a newline?

Comment: Add a breakpont and check the string

Comment: `response.trim()` also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805125/how-to-remove-all-line-breaks-from-a-string

Comment: `I've also checked that there is no white space before or after response text if it matters` - how? what is `console.log(response.length)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove all line breaks from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805125/how-to-remove-all-line-breaks-from-a-string)

Comment: Depending on your needs you could also test for a success status code instead of the text response. `response.status < 400` or of you want to specifically test for a 2xx status simply `response.ok`. See the [Response properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#Properties). However if you need to specifically match body text this might not fit your scenario.

Comment: fyi, newline characters are also considered whitespace characters. When you say *"I checked for whitespaces"* you meant "I checked for spaces".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use tim():

```
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.trim() === "success") {
        console.log("Test");
        this.draftList.splice(index, 1);
    }
});
```

Hope it'll work.

Comment: that would remove "whitespace", yeah? but the OP has checked and there are none

Comment: @JaromandaX maybe if we check the typeof the Response we can see if the === comparation works properly.

Answer (score 1):

There might be characters you don't see in the console (newlines, spaces, ...). To show them, you can use `JSON.stringify`:

```js
    console.log(" success\n"); // success, right?
    console.log(JSON.stringify(" success\n")); // no, not quite ...
```

To match while ignoring whitespace and newlines, use `response.trim() === "success"`, or `response.includes("success")`.

Comment: This question might not even have needed an answer imo.

Comment: Leaving a comment to answer this basic question is good enough, also closing it as a dup would also be good. There are plenty of answers talkinga bout how to remove spaces and new lines from strings. But just my opinion. Doesnt' matter in any case.

Comment: but OP determined no whitespace

Comment: the OP states he has checked for whitespace

Comment: @kemicofa if you have a good dupe at hand, I'll be glad to close-vote