# how to replace this special chars from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string like below:

```
JytLT1N=
Jy=rtyT1N=
tytTt=
yr=tyrtyr=
```

all of these lines ends with =CRLF

How can i remove them in javascript ?

**UPDATE:**

(=) is a fixed char at the end of all lines and after that (CRLF) is a line break char

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805125/how-to-remove-all-line-breaks-from-a-string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all line breaks from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805125/how-to-remove-all-line-breaks-from-a-string)

Comment: `string.trimRight("=CRLF");`

Comment: No. this does not help. CRLF is a special char for line break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the correct way.
The code below woks for me:

```
var str = "JytLT1N=
Jy=rtyT1N=
tytTt=
yr=tyrtyr=
";

const regex = /=\r?\n|\r/gm;
str.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
```

**Output:**
JytLT1NJy=rtyT1NtytTtyr=tyrtyr=

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
const str = `JytLT1N=
Jy=rtyT1N=
tytTt=
yr=tyrtyr=`;

alert(str.replace(/\n*\r*/g, ""));
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fwalid/1Lj0fzqh/4/

Comment: This does not handle carriage return.

Comment: I have updated my answer to handle the carriage return. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Carriage returns come before new lines