# How to convert string that is CSV but has \r\n and "," in fields into json?

Tags: node.js, string, csv

I have the following string and would like to convert it to json in javascript/node.js.

Issues:

1. It has \r\n not just \n
2. There are , in the fields, for example in the description
3. There are " which need to be removed but also could be in the description.

Perhaps there is a better way to process the multer.buffer than toString() ?

```
"name,description\r\nParis,The home of the eiffel tower\r\nMadrid,Madrid is home to two world-famous football clubs, Real Madrid and Atletico Madrid\r\n"
```

Prefered Output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Florida beach getaway",
        "description": "Soft beach sands, warm sunsets, calm waters"
    },
    {
        "name": "Iceland",
        "description": "Explore the dramatic landscape with volcanoes, geysers, hot springs and lava fields"
    }
]
```

I have tried csv-parse and papa-parse and neither are able to handle this line,

```
Madrid is home to two world-famous football clubs, Real Madrid and Atletico Madrid
```

Comment: Can you show which JSON you would like to get as a result?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=csv

Comment: rm the CRLF with a regex as show here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805125/how-to-remove-all-line-breaks-from-a-string    do the same to rm the comma