# Javascript/Jquery - Removing break line when copying and pasting text to textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I copy and paste text into a textarea, is there a way to ignore if there's line breaks and whitespaces?

For example,
When I highlight text below and copy paste into the textarea:

```
abcdef,
ghijkl,
mnopqrs
```

I want them to be in the text area:

```
abcdef,ghijkl,mnopqrs
```

ignore any whitespaces and line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `paste` event or `input` event (which covers paste and key events) and a regex to remove line break characters.

For explanation of the regex used see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10805198/1175966

```js
document.querySelector('textarea').addEventListener('input', function(){
   this.value = this.value.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
})
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>

<pre>
abcdef,
ghijkl,
mnopqrs
</pre>
```

Comment: Just verified. Working great. I really appreciate it!

Comment: It seems that with 'paste' doesn't work, only with 'input'