# Why CKEditor adding empty bullet points for my custom tags?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am getting extra blank bullet points for my HTML code in CKEditor. Also, the number of bullets are increasing when I change to source mode.https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-ckeditor-xck9uk?file=src/app/app.component.ts
[image]

```html
<ul>
    <my-tag id=""><li>test</li></my-tag>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
    <li>Test 3</li>
    <li>Test 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's how the editor is handling line breaks. Make it one line and it works `<ul><my-tag id=""><li>test</li></my-tag><li>Test 1</li><li>Test 2</li><li>Test 3</li><li>Test 4</li></ul>`

Comment: Hi @JonP, its HTML code, so there is no difference b/w single line and multiline, right?  I still getting the issue when change to source mode.

Comment: There is no difference to how the browser interprets it. There is a difference to how CKEditor handles it apparently. See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-ckeditor-5bztjl?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I can't remove this line, since the content comes from the backend server. @JonP Can you tap on the source button in the editor, then we are getting the same error.

Comment: I use the source button in the editor, which what clued me in initially. It is not an error per-se but how CKEditor handles multi-line source content added grammatically. See if there is way to configure it to handle  it better, or [use a regex to remove the line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805125/how-to-remove-all-line-breaks-from-a-string). If you click the source button in my previous example you'll see that the editor has formatted the code.

Comment: I don't want to re-format the HTML from my end. Is there is any config in CKEditor to handle the multi-line? Also why it happened only for custom tags?

Comment: OK, yes,  just noticed if we go with a formatted list of elements, line breaks etc it's fine. Another thing to remember CKEditor is an HTML editor. `<my-tag id="">` is not an known HTML tag nor is it a valid child of  `ul`. Simply put CKEditor doesn't know how to handle  invalid HTML and you will get inconsistent results due to that. On a quick check I couldn't find a config to overcome this. You may be stuck having to reformat the HTML

Comment: allowedContent will allow the custom tags in CKEditor.

Comment: It will allow them, but it doesn't mean that CKEditor will know what to do with them in terms of formatting them or in terms of HTML validation. You may get more joy with the CKE 4.0 Issues section on github : https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/issues