# Why I can't join all the string

Tags: javascript, string, testing, methods

I have a issue, I'm using JS.  Let's say I have this text separated by paragraphs:

Test hello

Test1 hello

Test2 hello

Test3 hello

and then I want to join all the paragraphs next to each other like this: Test hello Test1 hello Test2 hello Test3 hello, so I did this:

```
<pre>
var x = string.trim();
var xArr = x.match(/^\n|\S+/gm);
var xJoin = xArr.join(" ");
</pre>
```

but it continue as before with paragraphs, I try with string.replace() too. After the x.match(/^\n|\S+/gm) it brings me the array like this:

```
<pre>
[, ,
Test, hello

, ,
Test1, hello

, ,
Test2, hello

, ,
Test3, hello

, ,
 

]
</pre>
```

So this seemed a bit strange to me, could it be that it is not really separated by line breaks? Any idea how to put the strings next to each other? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805125/how-to-remove-all-line-breaks-from-a-string

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
const text = `Test hello

Test1 hello

Test2 hello

Test3 hello`;

console.log(text.split('\n').filter(t => !!t).join(" "));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix some minor issues in your code

1. Need to use replace if you want to replace new line with space
2. Need to remove `^` ( this start of string ) from you pattern

```js
let str = `Test hello

Test1 hello

Test2 hello

Test3 hello`


var x = str.trim();
var xArr = x.replace(/\n|\r|\r\n/gm, ' ');

console.log(xArr)
```

Comment: Hello, still not working.

Comment: @RocioFioranelli can you please elaborate what do you mean still not working ?

Comment: yes of course, after using trim and replace method the string is still separated into paragraphs. Same as this:                                                                                              let str = `Test hello

Test1 hello

Test2 hello

Test3 hello`

Comment: @RocioFioranelli here it's not a paragraph, it's single string, i am not getting your issue here

Answer (score 0):

Is your paragraph in an html element?
If so you can just use this:

```js
const textElement = document.getElementById("text");
console.log(textElement.innerText);
```

```html
<div id="text">
  Test hello

  Test1 hello

  Test2 hello

  Test3 hello
</div>
```

Or, put it in an html element created from your javascript before using the above method.

Otherwise you can try this regex? `text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");`