# How to remove extra character by Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How to remove white space from start and end, also I would like to remove the character "\n" and "\t" by Regex.
I only able to remove the white space like this way `replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'')`

`"   My name is\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRashel.   "`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you want the result to be "My name isRashel"?

Answer (score 1):

No need for a fancy regex. Just simply trim the string and then replace all sequences of consecutive white-space characters with a single space. Without more examples, this should work best.

```js
const input = '   My name is\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRashel.   ';

output.value = input.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
```

```html
<textarea id="output" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the whitespace from the start and end of strings, you can use  `trim()` on the strings, like this:

```js
stringName = stringName.trim();
```

This is also illustrated [here](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-remove-line-breaks-start-end-string).

To remove all line breaks and tabs in a string, you can use this regex `/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm`, like this:

```js
someText = someText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
```

This is also illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10805198/17396626).