# Trouble removing Carriage Return - Line Feed from string

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know there's a lot of posts on this, but the answers are not working for me.  Here's a link with good answers  - but did not work for me:  [How to remove all line breaks from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805125/how-to-remove-all-line-breaks-from-a-string)

and this is how I tried to remove tgh CR LF:

```
let newdata: string = JSON.stringify(data);
newdata =new String(newdata).valueOf();
// newdata = newdata.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '');
newdata = newdata.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '');
```

and I will post bothe a screenshot of the string in notepad++ so you can see it, then I will paste the string below if you want to test it.

[image]

and this is the string:

```
[{"type":"-","name":"aaSomeFile - Copy.txt","size":12,"modifyTime":1664204606000,"accessTime":1664981500000,"rights":{"user":"rw","group":"***","other":"***"},"owner":0,"group":0,"longname":"-rw-******    1 -        -
        12 Sep 26 11:03 aaSomeFile - Copy.txt"},{"type":"-","name":"SomeFile.txt","size":12,"modifyTime":1664204606000,"accessTime":1664204606000,"rights":{"user":"rw","group":"***","other":"***"},"owner":0,"group":0,"longname":"-rw-******    1 -        -              12 Sep 26 11:03 SomeFile.txt"},{"type":"-","name":"SomeFile1.txt","size":12,"modifyTime":1664204606000,"accessTime":1666806607000,"rights":{"user":"rw","group":"***","other":"***"},"owner":0,"group":0,"longname":"-rw-******    1 -        -              12 Sep 26 11:03 SomeFile1.txt"},{"type":"d","name":"TestFolder1","size":0,"modifyTime":1667511799000,"accessTime":1667511799000,"rights":{"user":"rwx","group":"***","other":"***"},"owner":0,"group":0,"longname":"drwx******    1 -        -               0 Nov  3 17:43 TestFolder1"},{"type":"-","name":"zzzSomeFile2.txt","size":12,"modifyTime":1664204606000,"accessTime":1666806623000,"rights":{"user":"rw","group":"***","other":"***"},"owner":0,"group":0,"longname":"-rw-******    1 -        -              12 Sep 26 11:03 zzzSomeFile2.txt"}]
```

Can anyone tell me how this can be removed?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you viewing / verifying that the strings contain CRLF? There's no display code in your question. Are you logging the values or using a debugger?

Comment: @Phil good question.  console.log(newdata ).  The above is the output from console.log.  I discovered this bucause the carriage return corrupts the json and it won't parse.

Comment: JSON can contain literal newlines just fine ~ https://jsfiddle.net/xjfy2hdo/. Perhaps you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist