# Underscore _.flatten with prefix of the to be flatten object

Tags: object, underscore.js, flatten

I need to flatten an object like this:

```
{
  ProductId: {
    Id: "123456-1234-1234-1234-123456789012",
    Type: "product",
    Name: "Product"
  }
}
```

to look like

```
{
  ProductId_Id: "123456-1234-1234-1234-123456789012",
  ProductId_Type: "product",
  ProductId_Name: "Product"
}
```

and I'm currently trying to archive that with underscore, but _.flatten doesn't have have a parameter for that.

Comment: Okay it seems someone got a solution for me already. https://gist.github.com/fantactuka/4989737

Comment: Not an exact duplicate (different flattening of properties, and not underscore-specific), but you might want to have a look at [Fastest way to flatten / un-flatten nested JSON objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19098797/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you ***.map*** and **.reduce**

```
var raw = {
      ProductId: {
        Id: "123456-1234-1234-1234-123456789012",
        Type: "product",
        Name: "Product"
      }
    },
    flatten = _.map(raw, function(item, k){
       return _.reduce(item, function(obj, val, key){ 
           obj[[k,key].join('_')] = val;
           return obj;
        }, {});
    });
console.log(flatten[0])
```