# Get value from javascript object 9

Tags: javascript, object

```
var params = {
"draw":"1",
"columns[0][data]":"0",
"columns[0][name]":"",
"columns[0][searchable]":"true",
"columns[0][orderable]":"true",
"columns[0][search][value]":"",
"columns[0][search][regex]":"false",
"columns[1][data]":"1",
"columns[1][name]":"",
"columns[1][searchable]":"true",
"columns[1][orderable]":"true",
"columns[1][search][value]":"",
"columns[1][search][regex]":"false",
"columns[2][data]":"2",
"columns[2][name]":"",
"columns[2][searchable]":"true",
"columns[2][orderable]":"true",
"columns[2][search][value]":"",
"columns[2][search][regex]":"false",
"order[0][column]":"0",
"order[0][dir]":"asc",
"start":"0","length":"10",
"search[value]":"",
"search[regex]":"false",
"_":"1407762649868"
}
```

If I want to get draw, I write code like this:

```
draw = params.draw;
```

So, my questions are:

1. how can I get search[value] value ?
2. how can I get _ value ?

Is that possible?

Comment: `params['search[value]']`, `params['_']`.

Comment: To access properties with invalid characters you can use bracket notation `params['search[value]']`

Comment: WOW.. That's work.. params['search[value]'], params['_'] thanks Ben, thanks adeneo

Comment: FWIW, `params._` works as well.

Comment: related: [unflatten JSON object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19098797/1048572) to expand the properties into a nested object that can be accessed "normally"