# How to input nested json to jquery tokeninput?

Tags: json, nested, jquery-tokeninput

I use  [jquery tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/).
A flatted json is no problem to be searched. but howto input nested object.

my code:

```
   var flat_obj = [{id: 7, name: "Ruby"}, {id: 11, name: "Python"}];
   var nested_obj = [{ "name": "main", "id": "2", "Parent": "0", "children": [{ "name": "submain", "id": "3", "Parent": "2"}] }];

   $("#search-input-local").tokenInput(nested_obj, { });
```

Comment: jQuery TokenInput doesn't handle nested JSON - you should format the JSON before you pass it to the plugin. What effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank u Chris, Is there a function to convert nested to flat object in javascript?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, to have every item in the TokenInput list, including the 'children'?

Comment: Yes, including the 'children'.

Answer (score 1):

TokenInput doesn't handle nested JSON, you will need to format the JSON correctly before you pass it to the plugin.

There are a number of libraries to flatten JSON, or take a look at [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19098797/1768779).