# findOneAndUpdate overwriting attributes in 2+ level deep object passed as doc

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Let's say I have this schema:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name : {
        firstName : String,
        lastName : String
    }
});
```

And I create this user:

```
User.create({
    name : {
        firstName : Bob,
        lastName : Marley
    }
}, function (err, user) {
    if(err) {
        return console.error(err);
    } else {
        return console.log(user);
    }
});
```

I noticed that if I do this:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: userId}, { name: { firstName : "Damian" } }, function (err, user) {
    if(err) {
        return console.error(err);
    } else {
        return console.log(user);
    }
});
```

My user now is:

```
user = {
    name : {
        firstName : "Damian"
    }
}
```

However, if I do this:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: userId}, { "name.firstName" : "Damian" }, function (err, user) {
    if(err) {
        return console.error(err);
    } else {
        return console.log(user);
    }
});
```

My user is:

```
user = {
    name : {
        firstName : "Damian",
        lastName : "Marley"
    }
}
```

Is there a way to pass an Object with not all of its attributes filled out to `findOneAndUpdate`, and keep the attributes that were there before, without getting rid of them? (same functionality as `$set` in Mongo). This is really annoying...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flatten your incomplete nested object with [flat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat), like this:

```
var flatten = require('flat')

flatten({
    name : {
        firstName : "Damian"
    }
})

// { 
//   'name.firstName': 'Damian'
// }
```

And now you can call `findOneAndUpdate` exactly as you did in your second example.

Comment: Oops, I actually tragically misunderstood your answer (as proposing removing one of the fields from schema...) and posted my own one - in the end actually using the same library. It's more elaborate, so I'm leaving it to be, but I'm not sure whether actually more helpful. +1 and sorry for duplicating your solution (by bad oversight).

Comment: Be very aware though that flattening might cause some weird things, like arrays in your data appearing as objects in your Mongo document. Consider an update like `{things: [1, 2]}`. Then `flatten({things: [1, 2]})` gives you `{ 'things.0': 1, 'things.1': 2 }` and `db.getCollection('...').updateOne({_id: ObjectId('...')}, {$set: { 'things.0': 1, 'things.1': 2 }})` will result in `things` (if it didn't exist already) being created as an object with keys '0' and '1', instead of an array. I found this out the painfully hard way. Use flat's `safe` option to prevent this.

Answer (score 4):

If you pass actual full nested object to `findOneAndUpdate()` (or any other `mongoose` update method):

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate({ ... }, {
  name: {
    firstName : "Damian"
  }
})
```

You will overwrite the *whole* (nested) object, therefore removing all of its other properties from the document (in this case: `lastName`).

To update only specific properties of the nested object, not the *whole* object, you need to use full path to the nested properties.

```
{ "name.firstName" : "Damian" }
```

(this will leave `lastName` in the nested `name` object untouched)

But it can be annoying to take care of that manually, whenever you update nested object's properties.

Luckily, it's not a problem at all to **flatten** the update object you pass to `findOneAndUpdate()` - so it never ends up being more than one level deep.

There are many ways to do this, debated upon in this question: [Fastest way to flatten / un-flatten nested JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098797/fastest-way-to-flatten-un-flatten-nested-json-objects) .

The quickest solution seems to be to use ready-made [`flat`](https://github.com/hughsk/flat) Node.js library.

```
var flatten = require('flat')

User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: userId },
  // same as passing '{ "name.firstName": "Damian" }':
  flatten({
    name: {
      firstName : "Damian"
    }
  }), function (err, user) {
  if(err) {
    return console.error(err);
  } else {
    return console.log(user);
  }
});
```