# How to manually flatten Elasticsearch nested JSON documents using Java?

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, flatten

I want to generate some documentation for my Elasticsearch document structure. The problem is that i'm storing nested JSON in my index but i want to document the flattend JSON format¹ that Elasticsearch is generating.

**Is there a way to flatten this JSON similar to the way that Elasticsearch is producing using the ES Java API?**

If possible i don't want to startup Elasticsearch for this task.

Example JSON:

```
{
  "title": "Nest eggs",
  "body":  "Making your money work...",
  "tags":  [ "cash", "shares" ],
  "comments": [ 
    {
      "name":    "John Smith",
      "comment": "Great article",
      "age":     28,
      "stars":   4,
      "date":    "2014-09-01"
    },
    {
      "name":    "Alice White",
      "comment": "More like this please",
      "age":     31,
      "stars":   5,
      "date":    "2014-10-22"
    }
  ]
}
```

The document will look like this once Elasticsearch has flattend it.

```
{
  "title":            [ eggs, nest ],
  "body":             [ making, money, work, your ],
  "tags":             [ cash, shares ],
  "comments.name":    [ alice, john, smith, white ],
  "comments.comment": [ article, great, like, more, please, this ],
  "comments.age":     [ 28, 31 ],
  "comments.stars":   [ 4, 5 ],
  "comments.date":    [ 2014-09-01, 2014-10-22 ]
}
```

[1] https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html

Comment: Would [something like this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/blowsie/S2hsS/show/light/) or [this](https://github.com/hughsk/flat) help? Other solutions are [available here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098797/fastest-way-to-flatten-un-flatten-nested-json-objects), too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote my own algorithm that flattens the Map which would be used to create the JSON.

```
private void flatten(Map<String, Object> map, Map<String, Object> output, String key) throws JSONException {
        String prefix = "";
        if (key != null) {
            prefix = key + ".";
        }
        for (Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String currentKey = prefix + entry.getKey();
            if (entry.getValue() instanceof Map) {
                flatten((Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue(), output, prefix + entry.getKey());
            } else if (entry.getValue() instanceof List) {
                output.put(currentKey, entry.getValue());
            } else {
                output.put(currentKey, entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage example:

```
    Map<String, Object> outputMap = new TreeMap<>();
    flatten(inputMap, outputMap, null);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(outputMap);
    String jsonStr = json.toString(4);
```

Comment: Have you tested it? How is it handling collections?

Comment: My model is only using lists, maps and strings. Lists are preserved and maps are collapsed. I have not yet encountered problems so far.

Comment: Glad you managed it to work. I asked because I did something very similar a few weeks ago and it was especially tricky to flatten collections of nested objects, when these objects were POJOs.