# One liner to flatten nested object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I need to flatten a nested object. Need a one liner. Not sure what the correct term for this process is.
I can use pure Javascript or libraries, I particularly like underscore.

I've got ...

```
{
  a:2,
  b: {
    c:3
  }
}
```

And I want ...

```
{
  a:2,
  c:3
}
```

I've tried ...

```
var obj = {"fred":2,"jill":4,"obby":{"john":5}};
var resultObj = _.pick(obj, "fred")
alert(JSON.stringify(resultObj));
```

Which works but I also need this to work ...

```
var obj = {"fred":2,"jill":4,"obby":{"john":5}};
var resultObj = _.pick(obj, "john")
alert(JSON.stringify(resultObj));
```

Comment: Why does this need to be in one line?

Comment: boss don't like me writing my own library funcs and I don't want to clutter code

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Object.assign({}, ...function _flatten(o) { return [].concat(...Object.keys(o).map(k => typeof o[k] === 'object' ? _flatten(o[k]) : ({[k]: o[k]})))}(yourObject))
```

Summary: recursively create an array of one-property objects, then combine them all with `Object.assign`.

This uses ES6 features including `Object.assign` or the spread operator, but it should be easy enough to rewrite not to require them.

For those who don't care about the one-line craziness and would prefer to be able to actually read it (depending on your definition of readability):

```
Object.assign(
  {}, 
  ...function _flatten(o) { 
    return [].concat(...Object.keys(o)
      .map(k => 
        typeof o[k] === 'object' ?
          _flatten(o[k]) : 
          ({[k]: o[k]})
      )
    );
  }(yourObject)
)
```

Comment: Worth noting that the `...` is ES6, so might not work on older browsers and older versions of nodejs etc.

Comment: doesn't handle null, or arrays properly

Comment: Do you think you can post a typescript version of this

Comment: @Eloff you can a conditional for array using Array.isArray() method and skip it if true

Answer (score 77):

**Simplified readable example, no dependencies**

```js
/**
 * Flatten a multidimensional object
 *
 * For example:
 *   flattenObject{ a: 1, b: { c: 2 } }
 * Returns:
 *   { a: 1, c: 2}
 */
export const flattenObject = (obj) => {
  const flattened = {}

  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    const value = obj[key]

    if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null && !Array.isArray(value)) {
      Object.assign(flattened, flattenObject(value))
    } else {
      flattened[key] = value
    }
  })

  return flattened
}
```

**Features**

- No dependencies
- Works with null values
- Works with arrays
- Working example https://jsfiddle.net/webbertakken/jn613d8p/26/

Comment: How would I extend the flatten example if I have several of these objects in an array?

Comment: You could `const myNewArray = myArray.map(item => flattenObject(item))`

Comment: It works, I got a [json](https://github.com/tik9/fun/blob/main/public/json/repos.json) that I want to flatten. Have a look at the key `edges` followed by `node`. Edges is an array, so your code does not work. I want to flatten by removing `node` and keep the rest.

Answer (score 35):

Here is a true, crazy one-liner that flats the nested object recursively:

```js
const flatten = (obj, roots=[], sep='.') => Object.keys(obj).reduce((memo, prop) => Object.assign({}, memo, Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[prop]) === '[object Object]' ? flatten(obj[prop], roots.concat([prop]), sep) : {[roots.concat([prop]).join(sep)]: obj[prop]}), {})
```

Multiline version, explained:

```js
// $roots keeps previous parent properties as they will be added as a prefix for each prop.
// $sep is just a preference if you want to seperate nested paths other than dot.
const flatten = (obj, roots = [], sep = '.') => Object
  // find props of given object
  .keys(obj)
  // return an object by iterating props
  .reduce((memo, prop) => Object.assign(
    // create a new object
    {},
    // include previously returned object
    memo,
    Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[prop]) === '[object Object]'
      // keep working if value is an object
      ? flatten(obj[prop], roots.concat([prop]), sep)
      // include current prop and value and prefix prop with the roots
      : {[roots.concat([prop]).join(sep)]: obj[prop]}
  ), {})
```

An example:

```js
const obj = {a: 1, b: 'b', d: {dd: 'Y'}, e: {f: {g: 'g'}}}
const flat = flatten(obj)
{
  'a': 1, 
  'b': 'b', 
  'd.dd': 'Y', 
  'e.f.g': 'g'
}
```

Happy one-liner day!

Comment: Thank you so much, I spent hours to find the way to flatten nested object. Your solution works perfectly to my case.

``
{"agama_id": "1", "jenis_kelamin": "1", "nama": "Emir", "nik": "3124125251", "no_handphone": "0822305152", "pekerjaan": "Programmer", "tanggal_lahir": new Date(), "tempat_lahir": "Kediri"}
``
I had this object that has nested object with a property that contains date value from Date object. Somehow it couldn't be flatten with others solutions. But your answer helps me.

I'm curious why the date can't be flatten. Anyone can explain?

Comment: This is a really nice function and if anyone finds this and would like a more human-readable version: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-engelbart-cdm1bm?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 8):

## ES6 Native, Recursive:

### **One-liner**

```js
const crushObj = (obj) => Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, cur) => typeof obj[cur] === 'object' ? { ...acc, ...crushObj(obj[cur]) } : { ...acc, [cur]: obj[cur] } , {})
```

### **Expanded**

```js
const crushObj = (obj = {}) => Object.keys(obj || {}).reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (typeof obj[cur] === 'object') {
    acc = { ...acc, ...crushObj(obj[cur])}
  } else { acc[cur] = obj[cur] }
  return acc
}, {})
```

### Usage

```
const obj = {
  a:2,
  b: {
    c:3
  }
}

const crushed = crushObj(obj)
console.log(crushed)
// { a: 2, c: 3 }
```

Comment: also mention how does the code addresses the requirement

Answer (score 8):

Here is a flatten function that correctly outputs array indexes.

```js
function flatten(obj) {
  const result = {};
  for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      const nested = flatten(obj[key]);
      for (const nestedKey of Object.keys(nested)) {
        result[`${key}.${nestedKey}`] = nested[nestedKey];
      }
    } else {
      result[key] = obj[key];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Example **Input**:

```json
{
  "first_name": "validations.required",
  "no_middle_name": "validations.required",
  "last_name": "validations.required",
  "dob": "validations.required",
  "citizenship": "validations.required",
  "citizenship_identity": {
    "name": "validations.required",
    "value": "validations.required"
  },
  "address": [
    {
      "country_code": "validations.required",
      "street": "validations.required",
      "city": "validations.required",
      "state": "validations.required",
      "zipcode": "validations.required",
      "start_date": "validations.required",
      "end_date": "validations.required"
    },
    {
      "country_code": "validations.required",
      "street": "validations.required",
      "city": "validations.required",
      "state": "validations.required",
      "zipcode": "validations.required",
      "start_date": "validations.required",
      "end_date": "validations.required"
    }
  ]
}
```

Example **Output**:

```js
const flattenedOutput = flatten(inputObj);
```

```json
{
  "first_name": "validations.required",
  "no_middle_name": "validations.required",
  "last_name": "validations.required",
  "dob": "validations.required",
  "citizenship": "validations.required",
  "citizenship_identity.name": "validations.required",
  "citizenship_identity.value": "validations.required",
  "address.0.country_code": "validations.required",
  "address.0.street": "validations.required",
  "address.0.city": "validations.required",
  "address.0.state": "validations.required",
  "address.0.zipcode": "validations.required",
  "address.0.start_date": "validations.required",
  "address.0.end_date": "validations.required",
  "address.1.country_code": "validations.required",
  "address.1.street": "validations.required",
  "address.1.city": "validations.required",
  "address.1.state": "validations.required",
  "address.1.zipcode": "validations.required",
  "address.1.start_date": "validations.required",
  "address.1.end_date": "validations.required"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

My ES6 version:

```js
const flatten = (obj) => {
    let res = {};
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            res = { ...res, ...flatten(value) };
        } else {
            res[key] = value;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: this will not keep the intermediate keys in the result so `{ a: { b: { c: { d: {` will only output `{ d: ... }` in the result instead of `{ 'a.b.c.d': ... }`

Answer (score 5):

It's not quite a one liner, but here's a solution that doesn't require anything from ES6.  It uses underscore's `extend` method, which could be swapped out for jQuery's.

```
function flatten(obj) {
    var flattenedObj = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            $.extend(flattenedObj, flatten(obj[key]));
        } else {
            flattenedObj[key] = obj[key];
        }
    });
    return flattenedObj;    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an ES6 version in TypeScript. It takes the best of answers given here and elsewhere. Some features:

- Supports Date objects and converts them into ISO strings
- Puts an underscore between the parent's and child's key (e.g. `{a: {b: 'test'}}` becomes `{a_b: 'test'}`

```
const flatten = (obj: Record<string, unknown>, parent?: string): Record<string, unknown> => {
    let res: Record<string, unknown> = {}

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        const propName = parent ? parent + '_' + key : key
        const flattened: Record<string, unknown> = {}

        if (value instanceof Date) {
            flattened[key] = value.toISOString()
        } else if(typeof value === 'object' && value !== null){
            res = {...res, ...flatten(value as Record<string, unknown>, propName)}
        } else {
            res[propName] = value
        }
    }

    return res
}
```

An example:

```
const example = {
    person: {
        firstName: 'Demo',
        lastName: 'Person'
    },
    date: new Date(),
    hello: 'world'
}

// becomes

const flattenedExample = {
    person_firstName: 'Demo',
    person_lastName: 'Person',
    date: '2021-10-18T10:41:14.278Z',
    hello: 'world'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a function I've got in my common libraries for exactly this purpose.
I believe I got this from a similar stackoverflow question, but cannot remember which (edit: [Fastest way to flatten / un-flatten nested JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19098797/697154) - Thanks Yoshi!)

```
function flatten(data) {
    var result = {};
    function recurse (cur, prop) {
        if (Object(cur) !== cur) {
            result[prop] = cur;
        } else if (Array.isArray(cur)) {
             for(var i=0, l=cur.length; i<l; i++)
                 recurse(cur[i], prop + "[" + i + "]");
            if (l == 0)
                result[prop] = [];
        } else {
            var isEmpty = true;
            for (var p in cur) {
                isEmpty = false;
                recurse(cur[p], prop ? prop+"."+p : p);
            }
            if (isEmpty && prop)
                result[prop] = {};
        }
    }
    recurse(data, "");
    return result;
}
```

This can then be called as follows:

```
var myJSON = '{a:2, b:{c:3}}';
var myFlattenedJSON = flatten(myJSON);
```

You can also append this function to the standard Javascript string class as follows:

```
String.prototype.flattenJSON = function() {
    var data = this;
    var result = {};
    function recurse (cur, prop) {
        if (Object(cur) !== cur) {
            result[prop] = cur;
        } else if (Array.isArray(cur)) {
             for(var i=0, l=cur.length; i<l; i++)
                 recurse(cur[i], prop + "[" + i + "]");
            if (l == 0)
                result[prop] = [];
        } else {
            var isEmpty = true;
            for (var p in cur) {
                isEmpty = false;
                recurse(cur[p], prop ? prop+"."+p : p);
            }
            if (isEmpty && prop)
                result[prop] = {};
        }
    }
    recurse(data, "");
    return result;
}
```

With which, you can do the following:

```
var flattenedJSON = '{a:2, b:{c:3}}'.flattenJSON();
```

Comment: This IS a one liner...

var flattenedJSON = flatten(myUnflattenedJSON);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19098797/697154 this one maybe? Also honestly, please don't answer questions like this one. They're bad for SO.

Comment: That looks like the one!

Answer (score 3):

Here are vanilla solutions that work for arrays, primitives, regular expressions, functions, any number of nested object levels, and just about everything else I could throw at them. The first overwrites property values in the manner that you would expect from `Object.assign`.

```
((o) => {
  return o !== Object(o) || Array.isArray(o) ? {}
    : Object.assign({}, ...function leaves(o) {
    return [].concat.apply([], Object.entries(o)
      .map(([k, v]) => {
        return (( !v || typeof v !== 'object'
            || !Object.keys(v).some(key => v.hasOwnProperty(key))
            || Array.isArray(v))
          ? {[k]: v}
          : leaves(v)
        );
      })
    );
  }(o))
})(o)
```

The second accumulates values into an array.

```
((o) => {
  return o !== Object(o) || Array.isArray(o) ? {}
    : (function () {
      return Object.values((function leaves(o) {
        return [].concat.apply([], !o ? [] : Object.entries(o)
          .map(([k, v]) => {
            return (( !v || typeof v !== 'object'
                || !Object.keys(v).some(k => v.hasOwnProperty(k))
                || (Array.isArray(v) && !v.some(el => typeof el === 'object')))
              ? {[k]: v}
              : leaves(v)
            );
          })
        );
      }(o))).reduce((acc, cur) => {
        return ((key) => {
          acc[key] = !acc[key] ? [cur[key]]
            : new Array(...new Set(acc[key].concat([cur[key]])))
        })(Object.keys(cur)[0]) ? acc : acc
      }, {})
    })(o);
})(o)
```

Also please do not include code like this in production as it is terribly difficult to debug.

```js
function leaves1(o) {
  return ((o) => {
    return o !== Object(o) || Array.isArray(o) ? {}
      : Object.assign({}, ...function leaves(o) {
      return [].concat.apply([], Object.entries(o)
        .map(([k, v]) => {
          return (( !v || typeof v !== 'object'
              || !Object.keys(v).some(key => v.hasOwnProperty(key))
              || Array.isArray(v))
            ? {[k]: v}
            : leaves(v)
          );
        })
      );
    }(o))
  })(o);
}

function leaves2(o) {
  return ((o) => {
    return o !== Object(o) || Array.isArray(o) ? {}
      : (function () {
        return Object.values((function leaves(o) {
          return [].concat.apply([], !o ? [] : Object.entries(o)
            .map(([k, v]) => {
              return (( !v || typeof v !== 'object'
                  || !Object.keys(v).some(k => v.hasOwnProperty(k))
                  || (Array.isArray(v) && !v.some(el => typeof el === 'object')))
                ? {[k]: v}
                : leaves(v)
              );
            })
          );
        }(o))).reduce((acc, cur) => {
          return ((key) => {
            acc[key] = !acc[key] ? [cur[key]]
              : new Array(...new Set(acc[key].concat([cur[key]])))
          })(Object.keys(cur)[0]) ? acc : acc
        }, {})
      })(o);
  })(o);
}

const obj = {
  l1k0: 'foo',
  l1k1: {
    l2k0: 'bar',
    l2k1: {
      l3k0: {},
      l3k1: null
    },
    l2k2: undefined
  },
  l1k2: 0,
  l2k3: {
    l3k2: true,
    l3k3: {
      l4k0: [1,2,3],
      l4k1: [4,5,'six', {7: 'eight'}],
      l4k2: {
        null: 'test',
        [{}]: 'obj',
        [Array.prototype.map]: Array.prototype.map,
        l5k3: ((o) => (typeof o === 'object'))(this.obj),
      }
    }
  },
  l1k4: '',
  l1k5: new RegExp(/[\s\t]+/g),
  l1k6: function(o) { return o.reduce((a,b) => a+b)},
  false: [],
}
const objs = [null, undefined, {}, [], ['non', 'empty'], 42, /[\s\t]+/g, obj];

objs.forEach(o => {
  console.log(leaves1(o));
});
objs.forEach(o => {
  console.log(leaves2(o));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an actual oneliner of just 91 characters, using Underscore. (Of course. What else?)

```js
var { reduce, isObject } = _;

var data = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: {
        d: 3,
        e: 4,
        f: {
            g: 5
        },
        h: 6
    }
};

var tip = (v, m={}) => reduce(v, (m, v, k) => isObject(v) ? tip(v, m) : {...m, [k]: v}, m);

console.log(tip(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://underscorejs.org/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
```

Readable version:

```js
var { reduce, isObject, extend } = _;

var data = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: {
        d: 3,
        e: 4,
        f: {
            g: 5
        },
        h: 6
    }
};

// This function is passed to _.reduce below.
// We visit a single key of the input object. If the value
// itself is an object, we recursively copy its keys into
// the output object (memo) by calling tip. Otherwise we
// add the key-value pair to the output object directly.
function tipIteratee(memo, value, key) {
    if (isObject(value)) return tip(value, memo);
    return extend(memo, {[key]: value});
}

// The entry point of the algorithm. Walks over the keys of
// an object using _.reduce, collecting all tip keys in memo.
function tip(value, memo = {}) {
    return _.reduce(value, tipIteratee, memo);
}

console.log(tip(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://underscorejs.org/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
```

Also works with Lodash.

Answer (score 2):

To **flatten only the first level** of the object and **merge duplicate** object keys into an array:

```js
var myObj = {
  id: '123',
  props: {
    Name: 'Apple',
    Type: 'Fruit',
    Link: 'apple.com',
    id: '345'
  },
  moreprops: {
    id: "466"
  }
};

const flattenObject = (obj) => {
  let flat = {};
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
      for (const [subkey, subvalue] of Object.entries(value)) {
        // avoid overwriting duplicate keys: merge instead into array
        typeof flat[subkey] === 'undefined' ?
          flat[subkey] = subvalue :
          Array.isArray(flat[subkey]) ?
            flat[subkey].push(subvalue) :
            flat[subkey] = [flat[subkey], subvalue]
      }
    } else {
      flat = {...flat, ...{[key]: value}};
    }
  }
  return flat;
}

console.log(flattenObject(myObj))
```

Answer (score 2):

Object.assign requires a polyfill. This version is similar to previous ones, but it is not using Object.assign and it is still keep tracking of parent's name

```
const flatten = (obj, parent = null) => Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, cur) => 
    typeof obj[cur] === 'object' ? { ...acc, ...flatten(obj[cur], cur) } :
    { ...acc, [((parent) ? parent + '.' : "") + cur]: obj[cur] } , {})

const obj = {
  a:2,
  b: {
    c:3
  }
}

const flattened = flatten(obj)
console.log(flattened)
```

Comment: this will not keep the root keys in the result so `{ a: [ { b, c } ] }` will only output `{ 0.b: ..., 0.c: ... }` in the result instead of `{ 'a.0.b': ..., 'a.0.c': ... }`

Answer (score 1):

```
function flatten(obj: any) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, current) => {
    const key = `${current}`;
    const currentValue = obj[current];
    if (Array.isArray(currentValue) || Object(currentValue) === currentValue) {
      Object.assign(acc, flatten(currentValue));
    } else {
      acc[key] = currentValue;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
};

let obj = {
  a:2,
  b: {
    c:3
  }
}

console.log(flatten(obj))
```

Demo
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-flatten-json

Answer (score 1):

Here goes, not thoroughly tested. Utilizes ES6 syntax too!!

```
loopValues(val){
let vals = Object.values(val);
let q = [];
vals.forEach(elm => {
  if(elm === null || elm === undefined) { return; }
    if (typeof elm === 'object') {
      q = [...q, ...this.loopValues(elm)];
    }
    return q.push(elm);
  });
  return q;
}

let flatValues = this.loopValues(object)
flatValues = flatValues.filter(elm => typeof elm !== 'object');
console.log(flatValues);
```

Comment: I just updated it to account for undefined and null values!

Comment: This returns an array, not an object

Answer (score 1):

I know its been very long, but it may be helpful for some one in the future

I've used recursion

```
let resObj = {};
function flattenObj(obj) {
    for (let key in obj) {
        if (!(typeof obj[key] == 'object')) {
            // console.log('not an object', key);
            resObj[key] = obj[key];
            // console.log('res obj is ', resObj);
        } else {
            flattenObj(obj[key]);
        }
    }

    return resObj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my TypeScript extension from @Webber's answer. Also supports dates:

```
private flattenObject(obj: any): any {
  const flattened = {};

  for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    if (isNullOrUndefined(obj[key])) {
      continue;
    }

    if (typeof obj[key].getMonth === 'function') {
      flattened[key] = (obj[key] as Date).toISOString();
    } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && obj[key] !== null) {
      Object.assign(flattened, this.flattenObject(obj[key]));
    } else {
      flattened[key] = obj[key];
    }
  }

  return flattened;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple typescript function which **flatten** object and **concatenates** keys:

```
function crushObj(
    rootObj:{[key: string]: any},
    obj: any,
    split = '/',
    prefix = ''
) {
    if (typeof obj === 'object') {
        for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
            const val = obj[key];
            delete obj[key];

            const rootKey = prefix.length > 0 ? `${prefix}${split}${key}` : key;

            crushObj(rootObj, val, split, rootKey)
        }
    }
    else {
        rootObj[prefix] = obj;
    }
}
```

You can use it like :

```
const obj = {
    name: 'John',
    address: {
      street: 'Aldo',
      number: 12,
    }
}
crushObj(obj, obj);
```

Results:

```
{
    name: "John",
    "address/street": "Aldo",
    "address/number": 12
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
  a:2,
  b: {
    c:3
  }
}
// recursive function for extracting keys
function extractKeys(obj) {
  let flattenedObj = {};
  for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)){
    if(typeof value === "object") {
      flattenedObj =  {...flattenedObj, ...extractKeys(value)};
    } else {
      flattenedObj[key] = value;
    }
  }
  return flattenedObj;
}
 
//  main code
let flattenedObj = extractKeys(obj);
console.log(flattenedObj);
```

Comment: This is the same as [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68047417/6036546) on this question by Marco Lackovic.