# Pushing keys and value from an inside Obj in the Parent object

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

Despite the fact that the title seems difficult, let me give you a simple example.
I have an object.

```js
{
  name:"Ethan"
  pets:{cat:"joline",dog:"Momo",bird"Mimi"}
}
```

My goal is to push the values of the array to the object.

```js
    {
      name:"Ethan",
      cat:"joline",
      dog:"Momo",
      bird"Mimi"
    }
```

The question is simple and I believe you can approach it in a clever way, thanks.

Comment: `[cat:"joline",dog:"Momo",bird"Mimi"]` is invalid javascript. `[` is used for array and arrays can't have `key:value` pairs

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, I have rectified the error.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513964/how-to-convert-this-nested-object-into-a-flat-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way to do this is to combine `pets` object and other properties using spread operator and then delete the `pets` from result.

```js
const data = {
  name:"Ethan",
  pets:{cat:"joline",dog:"Momo",bird:"Mimi"}
}

const res = {...data, ...data.pets};
delete res.pets;
console.log(res);
```

If you want to do it in a functional way you can use the following approach.

- Wrap the original element in a array.
- Apply `map` on it.
- Destructure `pets` from the object and store the rest of the properties in other variable.
- Return a new object where you spread the `rest` object and `pets`.

```js
const data = {
  name:"Ethan",
  pets:{cat:"joline",dog:"Momo",bird:"Mimi"}
}

const res = [data].map(({pets, ...rest}) => ({...rest, ...pets}))[0]
console.log(res)
```

Comment: The answer you provided is so clean. I'm going to test it soon and validate.

Comment: Please accept my best wishes for your well-being.

Comment: There is a problem with it, it overwrites or made disappear the "name".

Comment: @Ethanolle Thanks. If you don't understand anything feel free to ask. The first snippet has some error I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through the elements and values in the object. And spreading the value into the return object

```js
const data = {
  name: "Ethan",
  pets: {
    cat: "joline",
    dog: "Momo",
    bird: "Mimi"
  }
};

function flatten(data) {
  let result = {};

  for (const key in data) {
    const value = data[key];
    
    if (typeof value != 'object') result[key] = value;
    else result = { ...result, ... flatten(value)}
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(flatten(data));
```

Comment: ...tree? What does that mean?

Comment: It was the function call, I forgot to change it

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and cleanest way to obtain desired result with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
const obj = {
  name: "Ethan",
  pets: { cat: "joline", dog: "Momo", bird: "Mimi" },
};

const { name, pets } = obj;
const result = { name, ...pets };
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, this is straightforward with object destructuring.  I think it's cleanest when you use parameter destructuring.  So a simple function like this should do it:

```js
const promotePets = ({pets, ...rest}) => 
  ({...rest, ...pets})

const obj = {name: "Ethan", pets: { cat: "joline", dog: "Momo", bird: "Mimi" }};

console .log (promotePets (obj))
```