# what is the best way to map Javascript object with Quoted keys

Tags: javascript, api, object, key-value, nest-nested-object

I have received data from API like this

```
var myObj = {'name':'ahmed','age':37,'tools':{'dev1':"macbook",'dev2':"iphone",'dev3':"tablet"},'gender':'male'};
```

What is the best way to make it key-value pairs note that there are nested objects?

**update**
Thanks for the answer 
this is if I don't want to flatten my object

```
var myObj = {'name':'ahmed','age':37,'tools':{'dev1':"macbook",'dev2':"iphone",'dev3':"tablet"},'gender':'male'};


function unQuoteKeys(obj, newObj ={}){
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
          newObj[key] = obj[key]
    });
    return newObj
}
console.log(unQuoteKeys(myObj));
```

result

```
{ name: 'ahmed',
  age: 37,
  tools: { dev1: 'macbook', dev2: 'iphone', dev3: 'tablet' },
  gender: 'male' }
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean; that's an object. If you were to write `console.log(myObj.tools.dev1)` it would return "macbook"...

Comment: Please, if possible post the exact data structure the API is sending (as JSON). What you posted is a JavaScript Object.

Comment: are you looking for `JSON.parse(myObj)` or did you already do that?

Comment: That's not JSON, since JSON requires double quote marks (`"`), not single (`'`).

Comment: Duplicate (?) of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036487/one-liner-to-flatten-nested-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to flatten this whole object into a single set of key-value pairs. You can do this with a simple recursive function that adds the key/values to the return object if they are simple values, or recurses if the values are objects:

```js
var myObj = {'name':'ahmed','age':37,'tools':{'dev1':"macbook",'dev2':"iphone",'dev3':"tablet"},'gender':'male'};

function flatten(obj, res ={}){
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') flatten(obj[key], res)
        else res[key] = obj[key]
    })
    return res
}
console.log(flatten(myObj))
```

If there's the possibility that you will have duplicate keys anywhere in the object, this will need a bit more work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to flatten your object, you can also use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#flatten) `_flatten()` method. Works like a charm.