# how to replace object key with its inner array of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an Object Like This:

```
A={
    a:1,
    b:2,
    c:[{ca:3, cb:4, cc:5}],
    d:[{da:6, db:7, dc:8}],
    e:[{ea:9, eb:10, edc:11}]
}
```

How can i replace the keys: `c`, `d`, `e` with its inner values?

and get the result like this:

```
A={
    a:1,
    b:2,
    ca:3, 
    cb:4, 
    cc:5,
    da:6, 
    db:7, 
    dc:8,
    ea:9, 
    eb:10, 
    edc:11
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the code that you have tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55251598