# Create a flattened editable table from nested json with dynamic schema

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, angularjs, mongodb

I'm trying to create a UI component to display JSON data from MongoDB into an **editable** table in a **flattened** (2 dimensional) form. The JSON data is schemaless, so it can have any number/type of fields.

I'm open to using any UI framework.

I have tried using jquery [json-table-editor](https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/json-table-editor.html). It takes JSON array as input, gives a tabular view with editable cells, and supports nested objects without having to define columns explicitly.

But this has a limitation in that it doesn't have an option to display the data in flattened form instead it gives a table-within-table kind of view, like this:

[image]

I'm a backend developer having limited knowledge of UI(HTML and javascript), so I'm looking for a plugin that solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer here, on how to flatten objects. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55251598/12297696. Maybe you could use this function, to flatten the objects and then use the library you found for sake of efficiency. Regards.

Comment: But then, I have to take care of converting it back to JSON to save it in DB.