# Modifying an array with objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects each object has one nested object I need to modify that

Example: What I have below

```
const array = [{
    asset: {key: '1235', type: 'mocFirst'},
    id: 27,
    marketValuey: 6509,
    marketValueySecond: 65033,
    marketValueyThird: 650900,
}]
```

I want get that:

```
const array = [{
    type: 'mocFirst'
    key: '1235',
    id: 27,
    marketValuey: 6509,
    marketValueySecond: 65033,
    marketValueyThird: 650900,
}]
```

There is my solution

```
const array = [{
    asset: {key: '1235', type: 'mocFirst'},
    id: 27,
    marketValuey: 6509,
    marketValueySecond: 65033,
    marketValueyThird: 650900,
},
    {
        asset: {key: '12', type: 'mocFirst44'},
        id: 27,
        marketValuey: 6409,
        marketValueySecond: 64033,
        marketValueyThird: 640900,
    },
    {
        asset: {key: '1299', type: 'mocFirst'},
        id: 271,
        marketValuey: 6109,
        marketValueySecond: 61033,
        marketValueyThird: 610900,
    },
    {
        asset: {key: '1296', type: 'mocFirst'},
        id: 272,
        marketValuey: 65092,
        marketValueySecond: 650332,
        marketValueyThird: 6509020,
    },

]

    const resultArr = array.map(item => {
    const { asset, ...newObj} = item;
    const { key, type } = item.asset;
    return { key, type, ...newObj};

});
```

Any things about my solution? Maybe it can be done better? In production, I will have a big array

Comment: Looks fine.  Did you run into any trouble?

Comment: This isn't really the right site for reviewing working code, unless you have a specific problem to solve/goal to achieve (In which case, please include it in the question)

Comment: I don't recommend what was suggested about using `{ key:key }`.  The language has more concise syntax for that and it's just `{ key }` so keep using it as you are.

Comment: I have trouble with performance.  Below, I got an answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to transform `asset.key` and `asset.type` respectively into `key` and `type`, and you want to increase performance, manual assignment of fields is around 4-5 times faster than your solution.
*e.g.* I have created an `array` with 1000 items to compare your solution (which takes around 2.5 ms to create `array1`) with mine (around 0.5 ms to create `array2`).

```js
const N = 1000;
let array = [];
for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  let random_item = {
    asset: {
      key: Math.random(N),
      type: 'mocFirst'
    },
    id: Math.random(N),
    marketValuey: Math.random(N),
    marketValueySecond: Math.random(N),
    marketValueyThird: Math.random(N)
  };
  array.push(random_item);
}

const t0 = performance.now();
const array1 = array.map(item => {
  const {
    asset,
    ...newObj
  } = item;
  const {
    key,
    type
  } = item.asset;
  return {
    key,
    type,
    ...newObj
  };
});
console.log(array1[10]);
const t1 = performance.now();
console.log(`Operation took ${t1 - t0} milliseconds.`);

let array2 = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array2.push({
    key: array[i].asset.key,
    type: array[i].asset.type,
    id: array[i].id,
    marketValuey: array[i].marketValuey,
    marketValueySecond: array[i].marketValueySecond,
    marketValueyThird: array[i].marketValueyThird,
  });
}
console.log(array2[10]);
const t2 = performance.now();
console.log(`Operation took ${t2 - t1} milliseconds.`);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here you go, it's a recursive solution to flatten the object

```js
function flat(source, target) {
  Object.keys(source).forEach(function(k) {
    if (source[k] !== null && typeof source[k] === 'object') {
      flat(source[k], target);
      return;
    }
    target[k] = source[k];
  });
}

const array = [{
    asset: {
      key: '1235',
      type: 'mocFirst'
    },
    id: 27,
    marketValuey: 6509,
    marketValueySecond: 65033,
    marketValueyThird: 650900,
  },
  {
    asset: {
      key: '12',
      type: 'mocFirst44'
    },
    id: 27,
    marketValuey: 6409,
    marketValueySecond: 64033,
    marketValueyThird: 640900,
  },
  {
    asset: {
      key: '1299',
      type: 'mocFirst'
    },
    id: 271,
    marketValuey: 6109,
    marketValueySecond: 61033,
    marketValueyThird: 610900,
  },
  {
    asset: {
      key: '1296',
      type: 'mocFirst'
    },
    id: 272,
    marketValuey: 65092,
    marketValueySecond: 650332,
    marketValueyThird: 6509020,
  },

]
let flatArr = array.map(item => {
  let flatObj = {};
  flat(item, flatObj);
  return flatObj
});
console.log(flatArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just flatten it out like so:

```
var outArr = array.map(item => {
   // Create the new items
   item.key = item.asset.key
   item.type = item.asset.item
   // Delete the old parent
   delete item.asset
   return item
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The only speed-up that you can 'potentially' introduce is via the use of a `for loop` instead of a `map` method. This does unfortunately depend on how the compiler will optimize your code and the effects will only become noticeable if you are working with very large arrays.
Benchmarking can be referenced [here](https://leanylabs.com/blog/js-forEach-map-reduce-vs-for-for_of/).

The final part of your code should look like this:

```
const resultArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
  const { asset, ...newObj} = array[i];
  const { key, type } = asset;
  resultArr.push({ key, type, ...newObj});
}
```

It is important to understand that the speedup of this code will not be very noticeable and developers usually prefer more obvious/maintainable syntax, so your original answer can be considered correct. Hence, use this at your own discretion.

Answer (score 1):

I like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70377608/6672427), which I found by searching for "flatten nested object in javascript".

Here is the code in action from my favorite answer:

```js
const crushObj = (obj = {}) => Object.keys(obj || {}).reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (typeof obj[cur] === 'object') {
    acc = { ...acc, ...crushObj(obj[cur])}
  } else { acc[cur] = obj[cur] }
  return acc
}, {})

const obj = {
  a:2,
  b: {
    c:3
  }
}

const output = crushObj(obj)
console.log(output)
// { a: 2, c: 3 }
```

It would be great for a library like [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) to offer support for this.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a concept of destructuring.

```
array.map((elem) => {
 const {
    id, 
    marketValuey, 
    marketValueySecond, 
    marketValueyThird, 
    asset: {key}, 
    asset: {type}
 } = elem;
 
 return {
  id,
  marketValuey, 
  marketValueySecond, 
  marketValueyThird, 
  key, 
  type
  }
})
```

for more detailed concept of destructuring refer - [nested-destructuring](https://medium.com/@pyrolistical/destructuring-nested-objects-9dabdd01a3b8)