# More efficient ways to assign properties to an interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I assign the properties of an interface `CountersData` as seen below. I use a `flattenObject` to extract the most nested key and value data from `responseDeploymentData` (as detailed [One liner to flatten nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036487/one-liner-to-flatten-nested-object))

This is clunky, so is there a more efficient/simple way to do this? See code below:

```
interface CountersData {
  //more properties

  count_targets?: number;
  count_targets_excluded?: number;
  count_targets_pending?: number;
  count_targets_in_progress?: number;
  count_targets_completed?: number;
  count_targets_failed?: number;
}
// later in code
  const countersData = {} as CountersData;
  let targetData: any = flattenObject(responseDeploymentData);
  countersData.count_targets = targetData.count_targets;
  countersData.count_targets_excluded = targetData.count_targets_excluded;
  countersData.count_targets_pending = targetData.count_targets_pending;
  countersData.count_targets_in_progress = targetData.count_targets_in_progress;
  countersData.count_targets_completed = targetData.count_targets_completed;
  countersData.count_targets_failed = targetData.count_targets_failed;
```

**Updated Fix:**
`['count_targets', 'count_targets_excluded'].forEach(key => countersData[key] = targetData[key]);`

Comment: why not: `const countersData =  flattenObject(responseDeploymentData);`

Comment: @epascarello i just updated my code to indicate that I have more properties. That would not work with the functionality of my application.

Comment: `['count_targets', 'count_targets_excluded'].forEach(key => countersData[key] = targetData[key]);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
countersData = {
  ...countersData,
  ...flattenObject(responseDeploymentData)
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error `Cannot assign to 'countersData' because it is a constant.` I will update my code above to include line: `const countersData = {} as CountersData;`

Comment: Define countersData with "let" instead of "const" where it is initially defined. If this is not a possibility, then this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If `flattenObject(...)` returns the whole object which you need to put into `counterData`, then use:

```js
const counterData = flattenObject(...);
```

If `flattenObject(...)` only returns partial data, then you might want to do a destructuring assignment:

```js
const countersData = {} as CountersData;
const targetData: any = flattenObject(responseDeploymentData);

({
  count_targets: counterData.count_targets,
  count_targets_excluded: counterData.count_targets_excluded,
  count_targets_pending: counterData.count_targets_pending,
  count_targets_in_progress: counterData.count_targets_in_progress,
  count_targets_completed: counterData.count_targets_completed,
  count_targets_failed: counterData.count_targets_failed,
} = targetData);
```