# Angular - Map Object array value to same key

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an object like this,

```
const product = {
  name: 'watch',
  color: ['brown', 'white']
}
```

Expected result:

I need to flatten this object to below object format,

```
name: 'watch'
color: 'brown'
color: 'white'
```

To iterate the product object, I have to use another inner for-loop like below. Before iterating this outer for-loop, I need to flatten the input product object like above expected result. So that I can avoid the additional inner for loop to iterate the array values. How to simplify this?

```
    for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(product)) {
      if (Array.isArray(val)) {
        if (val.length) {
          for (const v of val) {
            console.log('Array val key:' + key + ', val:' + v);
          }
        }
      } else {
        console.log('key:' + key + ', val:' + val);
      };
    }
```

My tsconfig.json target is es2015(es6) and lib has es2017(es8) and es2018(es9). es10 and above features are not supported.

I saw Dennis Ameling answer here [One liner to flatten nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036487/one-liner-to-flatten-nested-object) which is somewhat identical to my requirement, but I don't need the array key to be appended to the parent object.

**Why I need to flatten this array value to same key?**

I have to push these key value to another array like,

```
let data = [];
this.data.push(`productkey${index}=${key}_productval${index}=${val}`);
```

I will push in this format to data array,

```
 productkey0=name_productval0=watch,
 productkey1=color_productval1=brown,
 productkey2=color_productval2=white,
```

Now with above for loop I have to use push method in outer for loop and inner loop. I want to simplify this.

Comment: It won't be possible to have 2 keys called `color` in the same object. `color` will take the value of the last assignment, so in your example above you would end up with `{ name: 'watch', color: 'white' }`. If you can provide an alternative request where all object keys are unique then a solution can be provided

Comment: You can't achieve this since `color` property appears twice. You can't do that and to understand why, try to answer the question about what value should you get when accessing  `flattenedObject.color`

Comment: I have updated the original question, why I want the array values of key to be mapped to same key again. I want to shorten the loop iteration code.

Comment: Stack overflow is not an appropriate venue to ask about how to optimize code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to shorten the loop iteration code, so that I can avoid the additional inner for loop to iterate the array values

This is not possible. You have a nested data structure, you will need nested loops to process it.

However, you can drop the superfluous `val.length` check, the loop body already won't run if the array is empty.

```
for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(product)) {
  if (Array.isArray(val)) {
    for (const [i, v] of val.entries()) {
      console.log('Array val key:' + key + '['+i+'], val:' + v);
    }
  } else {
    console.log('key:' + key + ', val:' + val);
  };
}
```