# How to convert a nested javascript object to only first level properties object?

Tags: javascript

I have the below object `inputObj` and I want to convert it to a simple object like `outputObj`.

```
var inputObj = {
    'a' : 1,
    'b' : true,
    'c' : 'string1',
    'd' : {
        'e' : 'string2',
        'f' : false,
        'g' : 5,
        'h' : {
            'i' : 7,
            'j' : 'string3',
            'k' : [
                {
                    'name' : 'l',
                    'value': 11
                },
                {
                    'name' : 'm',
                    'value': {
                        'n' : 13,
                        'o' : 'string4'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    'p' : [
        {
            'name' : 'q',
            'value': 15
        },
        {
            'name' : 'r',
            'value': 'Awesome!'
        }
    ]
}

var outputObj = {
    'a' : 1,
    'b' : true,
    'c' : 'string1',
    'e' : 'string2',
    'f' : false,
    'g' : 5,
    'i' : 7,
    'j' : 'string3',
    'l' : 11,
    'n' : 13,
    'o' : 'string4',
    'q' : 15,
    'r' : 'Awesome!'
}
```

Please note that in case of `array` the final output object would be build from `name` and `value` properties as per above example.

I have tried to implement the same using below code. I know as I am calling the nested function, the final object is getting reset and the scope is also different there. May be basic closure concept can solve this but I am confused with this. If you can correct my code or altogether new code is also fine.

```js
function convertToFirstLevelObject( object ) {
 var returnObj = {};

 if( IsPrimaryDataType( object )) {
  return object;
 }
 else {
  if( object instanceof Array ) {
         for ( var i = 0; i < object.length; i++ ) {
          if( typeof object[i] === 'object' && !(object[i] instanceof Array) ) {
           var key   = object[i]['name'],
            value = object[i]['value'];
           if( IsPrimaryDataType( value )) {
            returnObj[ key ] = value;
           }
           else {
            convertToFirstLevelObject( value );
           }
          }
          else{
           /* This condition is for Array of Array */
           if( object[i] instanceof Array ) {
            convertToFirstLevelObject( object[i] );
           } else {
            console.log('Wrong data passed, expected data id object or Array of objects');
            return;
           }
          }
         }
  }
  else {
   for ( var attr in object ) {
             if ( object.hasOwnProperty( attr ) ) {
              if( IsPrimaryDataType( object[ attr ] )) {
               returnObj[ attr ] = object[ attr ];
              }
              else {
               convertToFirstLevelObject( object[ attr ] )
              }
             } 
         }
  }
 }
 return returnObj;
}

function IsPrimaryDataType( input ) {
 var returnFlag = false;
 if( input === null || input === 'undefined' || typeof input !==  'object' ) {
  returnFlag = true;
 }
 return returnFlag;
}
```

**Edit:**
Here is another `inputObj` just to show that nesting can be of any level, here I have increased the level of array nesting. In any level of array nesting it will just look for if there is any object which has `name` and `value` both the property then it will flatten that.

```
 var inputObj = {
    'a' : 1,
    'b' : true,
    'c' : 'string1',
    'd' : {
        'e' : 'string2',
        'f' : false,
        'g' : 5,
        'h' : {
            'i' : 7,
            'j' : 'string3',
            'k' : [
                {
                    'name' : 'l',
                    'value': 11
                },
                {
                    'name' : 'm',
                    'value': [{'n' : 13},{'o' : 'string4'}]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    'p' : [
        {
            'name' : 'q',
            'value': 15
        },
        {
            'name' : 'r',
            'value': 'Awesome!'
        }
    ],
    's' : [
        [{
            'name' : 't',
            'value': 17
        },
        {
            'name' : 'u',
            'value': 'string5'
        }],
        [ 1, 2, 3],
        [ "string6", "string7", "string8"],
        [
            [1,3,5],
            [{'name' : 'v', 'value' : 19, 'anyOtherProp' : false}],
            [2,4,6],
            [{'name' : 'w', 'otherProp' : 31}]
        ]
    ]
}
```

OutObj should be like below

```
var outputObj = {
    'a' : 1,
    'b' : true,
    'c' : 'string1',
    'e' : 'string2',
    'f' : false,
    'g' : 5,
    'i' : 7,
    'j' : 'string3',
    'l' : 11,
    'n' : 13,
    'o' : 'string4',
    'q' : 15,
    'r' : 'Awesome!',
    't' : 17,
    'u' : 'string5',
    'v' : 19
}
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/penguinboy/762197

Comment: @Rayon [flattening JS objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19098797/1048572) is a completely different question

Comment: @Bergi – But input appears object, not `JSON`

Comment: I don't see `outputObj`. Anyway, in what way does your code fail? Have you tried walking through the code in the debugger?

Comment: @Rayon - Your solution may help me to solve my problem. But currently it will not yield the exact output object which I want.

Comment: @torazaburo - Sorry the representation is not so good, but there **scrollbar** where I have defined inputObj, you will find the outputObj at the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach for looping the object.

```js
function flatObject(source, target) {
    Object.keys(source).forEach(k => {
        if (Array.isArray(source[k])) {
            source[k].forEach(function iter(a) {
                if (Array.isArray(a)) {
                    a.forEach(iter);
                    return;
                }
                if (a !== null && typeof a === 'object') {
                    if ('name' in a || 'value' in a) {
                        'name' in a && 'value' in a && flatObject({ [a.name]: a.value }, target);
                        return;
                    }
                    flatObject(a, target);
                }
            });
            return;
        }
        if (source[k] !== null && typeof source[k] === 'object') {
            flatObject(source[k], target);
            return;
        }
        target[k] = source[k];
    });
}

var inputObj = { 'a': 1, 'b': true, 'c': 'string1', 'd': { 'e': 'string2', 'f': false, 'g': 5, 'h': { 'i': 7, 'j': 'string3', 'k': [{ 'name': 'l', 'value': 11 }, { 'name': 'm', 'value': [{ 'n': 13 }, { 'o': 'string4' }] }] } }, 'p': [{ 'name': 'q', 'value': 15 }, { 'name': 'r', 'value': 'Awesome!' }], 's': [[{ 'name': 't', 'value': 17 }, { 'name': 'u', 'value': 'string5' }], [1, 2, 3], ["string6", "string7", "string8"], [[1, 3, 5], [{ 'name': 'v', 'value': 19, 'anyOtherProp': false }], [2, 4, 6], [{ 'name': 'w', 'otherProp': 31 }]]] },
    target = {};

flatObject(inputObj, target);
console.log(target);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is really great solution. But can you please give little generic solution for `Array` part i.e. if I change my input like this `'value': [{'n' : 13},{'o' : 'string4'}]` in the `inputObj` (only `n`, `o` written here), then also it should work.

Comment: Sorry I think I couldn't convey my query properly, please see my **Edit** in the question. So `name` and `value` would be there, if any object inside array has these two property( i.e. `name` and `value`) then it will not flatten any other property.

Comment: I have tried executing and It doesn't give the expected `outputObj` with the updated `inputObj`. I think in your first solution you have assumed that  there will be objects containing `name` and `value` property just inside the array, but it is possible that there can be array of array (it can be of any level) and object inside inner array will have `name`, `value` property

Comment: ok, i see the problem. whot do you want with just array items whop are not objects with the wanted name value pair?

Comment: Those will be ignored in the `outputObj`. Like if an item inside array is a simple array that will be ignored. If an item inside array is an object having properties other than `name` and `value` those will be ignored.

Comment: This is just perfect which covers all the scenarios. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach. Very clear in my opinion. It relies heavily on recursion.

```
function convert(obj, mem) {
    if (typeof obj != 'object' || obj === null) { // return primitive values and null directly
        return obj
    }
    else if (obj.hasOwnProperty("name")) { // convert {name,value} objects to regular ones and recurse
        if (!obj.value) return // value is required - if not available bail out
        var o = {}
        o[obj.name] = obj.value
        return convert(o, mem)
    }
    else if (Array.isArray(obj)) { // iterate over array items and recurse
        obj.forEach(function (item) {
            convert(item, mem)
        })
    }
    else {
        for (var key in obj) { // iterate object items
            var value = obj[key]
            if (typeof value === "object") { // convert nested objects, dispose key
                convert(value, mem)
            }
            else {
                mem[key] = value // keep everything else
            }
        }
    }
    return mem // return result
}
```

Comment: btw, you can skip `else`, if you return in then part.

Comment: Sure. But i prefer to keep the `else` part. I find it much more readable this way.

Comment: @DrHund Thanks for the solution. I think it will fail for few conditions. Please see my new `inputobj`