# How to get or filter the nested object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a sample data object below, and I want to get the expected output data.

I have research and end to these sites but I'm having difficutly to apply it. [related-link1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-filter-nested-objects-in-javascript/) [related-link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410904/how-to-convert-a-nested-javascript-object-to-only-first-level-properties-object)

Someone knows how to do it in a shortest way as possible? thanks

---

My sample data:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        username: user_1,
        user: {
            name: 'Cuppelo'
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        username: user_2,
        user: {
            name: 'John'
        }
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        username: user_3,
        user: {
            name: 'Jane'
        }
    }
]
```

Expected output: `['Cuppelo', 'John', 'Jane']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the sample data array is saved to variable `users`, the following would give you a new array that matches your expected output:

```
users.map(ea => ea.user.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const user_1 = 'something';
const user_2 = 'something';
const user_3 = 'something';

const arr_1 = [
    {
        id: 1,
        username: user_1,
        user: {
            name: 'Cuppelo'
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        username: user_2,
        user: {
            name: 'John'
        }
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        username: user_3,
        user: {
            name: 'Jane'
        }
    }
];

const arr_2 = arr_1.map(obj => obj.user.name);

console.log(arr_2);
```