# Full path of a json object

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree

I'm trying to flatten an object where the keys will be the full path to the leaf node. I can recursively identify which are the leaf nodes but stuck trying to construct the whole path.

**Sample Input:**

```
{
  one: 1,
  two: {
    three: 3
  },
  four: {
    five: 5,
    six: {
      seven: 7
    },
    eight: 8
  },
  nine: 9
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
  one: 1,
  'two.three': 3,
  'four.five': 5,
  'four.six.seven': 7,
  'four.eight': 8,
  nine: 9
}
```

Comment: You can see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098797/fastest-way-to-flatten-un-flatten-nested-json-objects
Hope it can help you.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: @Victor I'm making api calls like api.moviestore.com/movies?where[movie.name:eq]=gravity. I need to flatten an object to construct the filter query.

Comment: @Sayem oh of course. I thought you just wanted to be able to get data by path or something.

Comment: This question is too broad, because there are many possible solutions. Try to write the code yourself, and if you encounter any specific problem, ask about it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use a recursive approch and collect the keys of the object. This proposal looks for arrays as well.

```js
function getFlatObject(object) {
    function iter(o, p) {
        if (o && typeof o === 'object') {
            Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
                iter(o[k], p.concat(k));
            });
            return;
        }
        path[p.join('.')] = o;
    }

    var path = {};
    iter(object, []);
    return path;
}

var obj = { one: 1, two: { three: 3 }, four: { five: 5, six: { seven: 7 }, eight: 8 }, nine: 9 },
    path = getFlatObject(obj);
 
console.log(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using newest JS features like Object spread and `Object.entries` it should be pretty easy:

```
function flatObj(obj, path = []) {
    let output = {};

    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([ key, value ]) => {
        const nextPath = [ ...path, key ];

        if (typeof value !== 'object') {
            output[nextPath.join('.')] = value;

            return;
        }

        output = {
            ...output,

            ...flatObj(value, nextPath)
        };
    });
}
```

Please note that this code is probably not the most optimal one as it copies the object each time we want to merge it. Treat it more as a gist of what would it look like, rather than a complete and final solution.

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution : 
Give the input as a full path to the function and it gives you the respective output

```
var obj = {
  one: 1,
  two: {
    three: 3
  },
  four: {
    five: 5,
    six: {
      seven: 7
    },
    eight: 8
  },
  nine: 9
};

function deepFind(obj, path) {
  var paths = path.split('.')
    , current = obj
    , i;

  for (i = 0; i < paths.length; ++i) {
    if (current[paths[i]] == undefined) {
      return undefined;
    } else {
      current = current[paths[i]];
    }
  }
  return current;
}

console.log(deepFind(obj, 'four.six.seven'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
  one: 1,
  two: {
    three: 3
  },
  four: {
    five: 5,
    six: {
      seven: 7
    },
    eight: 8
  },
  nine: 9
};

function flatten(obj) {
  var flatObj = {}

  function makeFlat(obj, path) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    if (keys.length) {
      keys.forEach(function (key) {
        makeFlat(obj[key], (path ? path + "." : path) + key);
      })
    } else {
      flatObj[path] = obj;
    }
  }
  makeFlat(obj, "");
  return flatObj;
}

console.log(flatten(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

A non fancy approach, internally uses recursion.

```js
var x = { one:1,two:{three:3},four:{five: 5,six:{seven:7},eight:8},nine:9};
var res = {};
var constructResultCurry = function(src){ return constructResult(res,src); }
        
function constructResult(target, src) {
  if(!src) return;
  target[src.key] = src.val;
}
        
function buildPath(key, obj, overAllKey) {
  overAllKey += (overAllKey ? "." : "") + key;
  if(typeof obj[key] != "object") return { key : overAllKey, val : obj[key] };
  Object.keys(obj[key]).forEach(function(keyInner) {
     constructResultCurry(buildPath(keyInner, obj[key], overAllKey));  
  });
}
        
Object.keys(x).forEach(function(k){
  constructResultCurry(buildPath(k, x, ""));
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might simply do as follows;

```js
var obj = {one: 1, two: {three: 3}, four: {five: 5, six: {seven: 7}, eight: 8}, nine: 9},
flatObj = (o,p="") => { return Object.keys(o)
                                     .map(k => o[k] === null           ||
                                               typeof o[k] !== "object" ? {[p + (p ? ".":"") + k]:o[k]}
                                                                        : flatObj(o[k],p + (p ? ".":"") + k))
                                     .reduce((p,c) => Object.assign(p,c));
                      };
console.log(flatObj(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a tiny JavaScript utility to access properties using path. It is called [object-path](https://github.com/mariocasciaro/object-path) and is an opensource project on GitHub.

To get attribute from an object:

```
objectPath.get(obj, "a.b");
```

to set attribute:

```
objectPath.set(obj, "a.b", value);
```

to remove an attribute:

```
objectPath.del(obj, "a.b");
```

So easy!!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using this function:

```js
const obj = {
  one: 1,
  two: {
    three: 3
  },
  four: {
    five: 5,
    six: {
      seven: 7
    },
    eight: 8
  },
  nine: 9
}


const flatObject = (obj, keyPrefix = null) =>
  Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
    const nextKey = keyPrefix ? `${keyPrefix}.${key}` : key

    if (typeof val !== "object") {
      return {
        ...acc,
        [nextKey]: val
      };
    } else {
      return {
        ...acc,
        ...flatObject(val, nextKey)
      };
    }

  }, {});
  
  console.log(flatObject(obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interative solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan).

`object-scan` is a data processing tool, so the main advantage here is that it would be easy to do further processing or processing while extracting the desired information

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const myData = { one: 1, two: { three: 3 }, four: { five: 5, six: { seven: 7 }, eight: 8 }, nine: 9 };

const flatten = (data) => {
  const entries = objectScan(['**'], {
    reverse: false,
    rtn: 'entry',
    joined: true,
    filterFn: ({ isLeaf }) => isLeaf
  })(data);
  return Object.fromEntries(entries);
};

console.log(flatten(myData));
// => { one: 1, 'two.three': 3, 'four.five': 5, 'four.six.seven': 7, 'four.eight': 8, nine: 9 }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
let x;
try{
  x = JSON.parse(prompt("Input your JSON"))
}
catch(e) {
   alert("not a valid json input")
}
var res = {};
var constructResultCurry = function(src){ return constructResult(res,src); }
        
function constructResult(target, src) {
  if(!src) return;
  target[src.key] = src.val;
}
        
function buildPath(key, obj, overAllKey) {
  overAllKey += (overAllKey ? "." : "") + key;
  if(typeof obj[key] != "object") return { key : overAllKey, val : obj[key] };
  Object.keys(obj[key]).forEach(function(keyInner) {
     constructResultCurry(buildPath(keyInner, obj[key], overAllKey));  
  });
}
        
Object.keys(x).forEach(function(k){
  constructResultCurry(buildPath(k, x, ""));
});
console.log("**************ALL FIELDS****************")
console.log(res);
console.log("******************************************")

let conf = confirm("do you need a specific field from JSON");
if ( conf )
{
   let field = prompt("Input field name")
   let results = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(res).filter(([key]) => (key.toLowerCase()).includes((field.toLowerCase()))))
  prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", JSON.stringify(results));
   console.log(results)
   
} 
else {
   prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", JSON.stringify(res));
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/amars404/2n9fprz8/57/