# Get array fields name

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

So i have this kind of array from json

```
data : [{
    article_categories : {
        id : "xxx",
        name : "xxx"
    },
    article : "xxx",
    publisher : "xxx"
}]
```

I wanted to create another multi dimension array for those array and i want to keep the fields name (the name `"article"`,`"publisher"` and so on in the array)  with value in there but i have no idea to get fields name

And i also want to do some conditional if to only include some fields into my new array by checking from this array

```
thead: [
    { key: "article"},
    { key: "article_categories.name"},
    .....
]
```

so i the end there will be array like this

```
newArray: [
 {article:"xxx",publisher: "xxx",article_categories.name:"xxx"},
 {article:"xxx",publisher: "xxx",article_categories.name:"xxx"}
 ....
]
```

how to do that? i tried

```
thead.forEach(function(column){
  data.forEach(function(key,value){
      if(column.key == key){
         newArray[key] = value
      }
  })
})
```

but it just not working....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're open to use [lodash](https://lodash.com/), it will be so simple. Lodash is efficient in evaluating JSON expressions using `.get()` method, so you won't be bothered to evaluate the expression against objects.

`.chain()` adds icing on the cake, making the code simpler to read, yet performing many complex operations under the hood.

Try the following snippet:

```js
var keys = [{
    key: "article"
  },
  {
    key: "article_categories.name"
  }
];

var data = [{
  article_categories: {
    id: "xxx",
    name: "xxx"
  },
  article: "xxx",
  publisher: "xxx"
}];

var result = _.chain(data)
  .map(function(item) {
    var object = {};

    keys.forEach(function(key) {
      object[key.key] = _.get(item, key.key);
    });

    return object;
  })
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That requires loading a 70kb (minified!) library just to iterate through an array... :/

Comment: well i already using lodash so i don;t mind it, but sorry i have another question but still related to this... what if my thead json array is an object and be like this thead: { article : "string", publisher: "string", ....} how do i modified those code?

Comment: @LaurensiusTony -- In that case, you will only be interested in the object's keys. So, you can replace `keys.forEach` with `_.keys(tdata).forEach( ... )`.

Comment: tdata is what? and also i still don't quite understand your code, it so simple that is seems like a magic...

Answer (score 1):

I think that first, you should simplify this :

```
thead = [
    { key: "article"},
    { key: "article_categories.name"},
    .....
]
```

as this :

```
thead = ["article", "article_categories.name"]
```

Here's my go at it :

```js
const data = [{
  article_categories : {
   id : "xxx",
   name : "xxx"
  },
  article : "xxx",
  publisher : "xxx"
 }],
 thead = ["article", "article_categories.name"]

const newArray = data.map( obj => {
 let output = {}
 thead.forEach(key => {
  if(key.includes(".")){
   let subkeys = key.split(".")
   output[key] = obj[subkeys[0]][subkeys[1]]
  } else {
   output[key] = obj[key]
  }
 })
 return output
})

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: What if `article_categories.name` is changed to something like `a.b[0].c`? Using lodash is a pain in terms of loading a library, but is better suited in this case because parsing JSON expression and evaluating it is something like reinventing the wheel, and is of-course prone to errors.

Comment: If it's changed, then the code will need to be adjusted. In the meantime, OP said nothing about changing it, this answers the question and doesn't load a 70k library ;)

Comment: Haha, that justifies it for now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42156958/427146) function to flatten the object with dot notation.

Then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the flattened object to take an `item` each and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) only the `key`s that are allowed and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a) to reconstruct the object.

To answer your original question, you can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the `keys` of an Object

```js
let data = [{
    article_categories : {
        id : "xxx",
        name : "xxx"
    },
    article : "xxx",
    publisher : "xxx"
},{
    article_categories : {
        id : "xxx2",
        name : "xxx2"
    },
    article : "xxx2",
    publisher : "xxx2"
}]

let thead = [
    { key: "article"},
    { key: "article_categories.name"},
];

let allowed_keys = thead.map(x=> x.key);

let flattened = data.map(item => flatten(item, '', ''));

// console.log(flattened);

let result = flattened.map(item => {
  return Object.keys(item)
    .filter(key => allowed_keys.includes(key))
    .reduce((obj, key) => {
      obj[key] = item[key];
      return obj;
    }, {})
});

console.log(result);


/**
 * Recursively flattens a JSON object using dot notation.
 *
 * NOTE: input must be an object as described by JSON spec. Arbitrary
 * JS objects (e.g. {a: () => 42}) may result in unexpected output.
 * MOREOVER, it removes keys with empty objects/arrays as value (see
 * examples bellow).
 *
 * @example
 * // returns {a:1, 'b.0.c': 2, 'b.0.d.e': 3, 'b.1': 4}
 * flatten({a: 1, b: [{c: 2, d: {e: 3}}, 4]})
 * // returns {a:1, 'b.0.c': 2, 'b.0.d.e.0': true, 'b.0.d.e.1': false, 'b.0.d.e.2.f': 1}
 * flatten({a: 1, b: [{c: 2, d: {e: [true, false, {f: 1}]}}]})
 * // return {a: 1}
 * flatten({a: 1, b: [], c: {}})
 *
 * @param obj item to be flattened
 * @param {Array.string} [prefix=[]] chain of prefix joined with a dot and prepended to key
 * @param {Object} [current={}] result of flatten during the recursion
 *
 * @see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation
 */
function flatten (obj, prefix, current) {
  prefix = prefix || []
  current = current || {}
  if (typeof (obj) === 'object' && obj !== null) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
      flatten(obj[key], prefix.concat(key), current)
    })
  } else {
    current[prefix.join('.')] = obj
  }
  return current
}
```