# Find a full object path to a given value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with items (only have `name` property) and groups (with a `children` property, they may contain items or other groups) and I need to get a full path to `needle` value, so in this case it'd be `myObj[2]["children"][0]["children"][1]["children"][0]`, plus I'm limited to quite old JS version ECMA 262 (I'm using it inside Photoshop)

```
var myObj = [
{
    "name": "group1",
    "children": [
    {
        "name": "group2",
        "children": [
        {
            "name": "item0"
        }]
    }]
},
{
    "name": "item1"
},
{
    "name": "needleGroup",
    "children": [
    {
        "name": "needleNestedGroup",
        "children": [
        {
            "name": "item3"
        },
        {
            "name": "needleNestedDeeperGroup",
            "children": [
            {
                "name": "needle"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}];
```

My first idea was to transform object to array or arrays so it'd be easier to process, so my object became

```
[
    [
        [
            "item0"
        ]
    ],
    "item1", 
    [
        [
            "item3", 
            [
                "needle"
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

But.. that's it. I can't figure out hot to track down only the indexes I need. Could you please point out a correct direction.

Comment: What is _"JavaScript EX4"_?

Comment: sorry, I should've write ECMA 262 (version/edition 3). It's a javascript engine inside Photoshop, I'll update my question

Comment: Does this version of ES have recursion and `Array#join`?

Comment: yes, almost everything before let/const/arrow functions

Comment: This should be a good starting point: [Fastest way to flatten / un-flatten nested JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19098797/218196)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a recursive function to look for the item you want. Once the function find it, it will return an array. Each step back of the recursion will `unshift` the object key of this step:

```
function find(obj, item) {
    for(var key in obj) {                                   // for each key in obj (obj is either an object or an array)
        if(obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === "object") {      // if the current property (value of obj[key]) is also an object/array
            var result = find(obj[key], item);              // try finding item in that object
            if(result) {                                    // if we find it
                result.unshift(key);                        // we shift the current key to the path array (result will be an array of keys)
                return result;                              // and we return it to our caller
            }
        } else if(obj[key] === item) {                      // otherwise (if obj[key] is not an object or array) we check if it is the item we're looking for
            return [key];                                   // if it is then we return the path array (this is where the path array get constructed)
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this function will be an array of keys leading to `item`. You can easily transform it to the format in the question:

```
function findFormatted(obj, item) {
    var path = find(obj, item);                             // first let's get the path array to item (if it exists)
    if(path == null) {                                      // if it doesn't exist
        return "";                                          // return something to signal its inexistance
    }
    return 'myObj["' + path.join('"]["') + '"]';            // otherwise format the path array into a string and return it
}
```

**Example:**

```js
function find(obj, item) {
    for(var key in obj) {
        if(obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === "object") {
            var result = find(obj[key], item);
            if(result) {
                result.unshift(key);
                return result;
            }
        } else if(obj[key] === item) {
            return [key];
        }
    }
}

function findFormatted(obj, item) {
    var path = find(obj, item);
    if(path == null) {
        return "";
    }
    return 'myObj["' + path.join('"]["') + '"]';
}

var myObj = [{"name":"group1","children":[{"name":"group2","children":[{"name":"item0"}]}]},{"name":"item1"},{"name":"needleGroup","children":[{"name":"needleNestedGroup","children":[{"name":"item3"},{"name":"needleNestedDeeperGroup","children":[{"name":"needle"}]}]}]}];

console.log("find(myObj, \"needle\"):          " + JSON.stringify(find(myObj, "needle")));
console.log("findFormatted(myObj, \"needle\"): " + findFormatted(myObj, "needle"));
```

**Note:** The indexes for the arrays are also formatted as strings, but that won't be a problem as `someArray["2"]` is equivalent to `someArray[2]`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I need to learn more about recursive functions, I don't think I understand how exactly your example works

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy You're welcome! Recursion is bit tricky to understand but you'll get it eventually. There is plenty of resources about online. Happy reading!

Answer (score 1):

I've created something you might use. The code below returns an Array of paths to keys, values, objects you are looking for.

See snippet and example to see what you can do.

To make it work you have to pass key and/or value you want to find in element and element which is an Array or Object.

It's written in newer JS standard but it shouldn't be a problem to compile it to older standard.

```js
function findKeyValuePairsPath(keyToFind, valueToFind, element) {
  if ((keyToFind === undefined || keyToFind === null) &&
    (valueToFind === undefined || valueToFind === null)) {
    console.error('You have to pass key and/or value to find in element!');
    return [];
  }

  const parsedElement = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(element));
  const paths = [];

  if (this.isObject(parsedElement) || this.isArray(parsedElement)) {
    checkObjOrArr(parsedElement, keyToFind, valueToFind, 'baseElement', paths);
  } else {
    console.error('Element must be an Object or Array type!', parsedElement);
  }

  console.warn('Main element', parsedElement);
  return paths;
}

function isObject(elem) {
  return elem && typeof elem === 'object' && elem.constructor === Object;
}

function isArray(elem) {
  return Array.isArray(elem);
}

function checkObj(obj, keyToFind, valueToFind, path, paths) {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (!keyToFind && valueToFind === value) {
      // we are looking for value only
      paths.push(`${path}.${key}`);
    } else if (!valueToFind && keyToFind === key) {
      // we are looking for key only
      paths.push(path);
    } else if (key === keyToFind && value === valueToFind) {
      // we ale looking for key: value pair
      paths.push(path);
    }

    checkObjOrArr(value, keyToFind, valueToFind, `${path}.${key}`, paths);
  });
}

function checkArr(array, keyToFind, valueToFind, path, paths) {
  array.forEach((elem, i) => {
    if (!keyToFind && valueToFind === elem) {
      // we are looking for value only
      paths.push(`${path}[${i}]`);
    }
    checkObjOrArr(elem, keyToFind, valueToFind, `${path}[${i}]`, paths);
  });
}

function checkObjOrArr(elem, keyToFind, valueToFind, path, paths) {
  if (this.isObject(elem)) {
    checkObj(elem, keyToFind, valueToFind, path, paths);
  } else if (this.isArray(elem)) {
    checkArr(elem, keyToFind, valueToFind, path, paths);
  }
}

const example = [
  {
    exampleArr: ['lol', 'test', 'rotfl', 'yolo'],
    key: 'lol',
  },
  {
    exampleArr: [],
    key: 'lol',
  },
  {
    anotherKey: {
      nestedKey: {
        anotherArr: ['yolo'],
      },
      anotherNestedKey: 'yolo',
    },
    emptyKey: null,
    key: 'yolo',
  },
];

console.log(findKeyValuePairsPath('key', 'lol', example)); // ["baseElement[0]", "baseElement[1]"]
console.log(findKeyValuePairsPath(null, 'yolo', example)); // ["baseElement[0].exampleArr[3]", "baseElement[2].anotherKey.nestedKey.anotherArr[0]", "baseElement[2].anotherKey.anotherNestedKey", "baseElement[2].key"]
console.log(findKeyValuePairsPath('anotherNestedKey', null, example)); //["baseElement[2].anotherKey"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I came accross this issue and took the chance to create find-object-paths, which solves this problem: Finding paths in an object by either keys, values or key/value combinations.

NPM: [find-object-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-object-paths)

Github: [getPaths](https://github.com/maugenst/getPaths)

Example object:

```
{
          "company": {
            "name": "ACME INC",
            "address": "1st Street, Toontown, TT",
            "founded": "December 31st 1969",
            "hasStocks": true,
            "numberOfEmployees": 2,
            "numberOfActors": 3
          },
          "employees": [
            {
              "employeeNumber": 1,
              "name": "Hugo Boss",
              "age": 65,
              "isCEO": true
            },
            {
              "employeeNumber": 2,
              "name": "Herbert Assistant",
              "age": 32,
              "isCEO": false
            }
          ],
          "actors": [
            {
              "actorId": 1,
              "name": "Bugs Bunny",
              "retired": false,
              "playedIn": [
                {
                  "movie": "Who Framed Roger Rabbit",
                  "started": 1988
                },
                {
                  "movie": "Space Jam",
                  "started": 1996
                },
                {
                  "movie": "Looney Tunes: Back in Action",
                  "started": 2003
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "actorId": 2,
              "name": "Pepé le Pew",
              "retired": true,
              "playedIn": [
                {
                  "movie": "For Scent-imental Reasons",
                  "started": 1949
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "actorId": 3,
              "name": "Marvin the Martian",
              "retired": true,
              "playedIn": [
                {
                  "movie": "Marvin the Martian in the Third Dimension",
                  "started": 1996
                },
                {
                  "movie": "Duck Dodgers and the Return of the 24½th Century",
                  "started": 1980
                },
                {
                  "movie": "Hare-Way to the Stars",
                  "started": 1958
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "actorId": 4,
              "name": "Yosemite Sam",
              "retired": false,
              "playedIn": [
                {
                  "movie": "Who Framed Roger Rabbit",
                  "started": 1988
                },
                {
                  "movie": "Space Jam",
                  "started": 1996
                },
                {
                  "movie": "Looney Tunes: Back in Action",
                  "started": 2003
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "distributionChannels": [
            "Celluloyd",
            [
              "VHS",
              "Betamax",
              "DVD",
              "Blueray"
            ],
            [
              "channel",
              12,
              true
            ]
          ]
    }
```

So, the basic usage could be:

```
import { findObjectPaths } from 'findObjectPaths';

class TestMe {

    static async main() {
        let acmeInc = {};
        rawFileContent = fs.readFileSync(p.resolve(__dirname, 'acmeInc.json'), 'utf-8');
        acmeInc = JSON.parse(rawFileContent);

        let path = findObjectPaths(acmeInc, {key: 'founded'});
        // company.founded
        path = findObjectPaths(acmeInc, {value: 'December 31st 1969'});
        // company.founded

        const allPaths: string[] = findObjectPaths(acmeInc, {key: 'actorId'}) as string[];
        /* [ 'actors[0].actorId',
             'actors[1].actorId',
             'actors[2].actorId',
             'actors[3].actorId' ]
         */

        const ceoPath = findObjectPaths(acmeInc, {key: 'isCEO', value: true});
         // employees[0].isCEO
    }
}

TestMe.main();
```

See the full documentation here: https://github.com/maugenst/getPaths#readme

BR

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a nested and repetitive pattern of objects in your data-set, the following solution would do the trick for you.

```js
const nodePath = { value: [] };

function findTreeNodeAndPath(
  targetNodeKey,
  targetNodeValue,
  nodeChildrenKey,
  tree
) {
  if (tree[targetNodeKey] === targetNodeValue) {
    nodePath.value.push(tree);
    return;
  }

  if (tree[nodeChildrenKey].length > 0) {
    tree[nodeChildrenKey].forEach(children => {
      if (nodePath.value.length < 1) {
        findTreeNodeAndPath(
          targetNodeKey,
          targetNodeValue,
          nodeChildrenKey,
          children
        );
      }
    });
  } else if (tree[nodeChildrenKey].length === 0) {
    return;
  }

  if (nodePath.value.length > 0) {
    nodePath.value.push(tree);
  }
}

const exampleData = {
  name: "Root",
  children: [
    {
      name: "A2",
      children: [
        {
          name: "AC1",
          children: [
            {
              name: "ACE1",
              children: []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "AC2",
          children: [
            {
              name: "ACF1",
              children: []
            },
            {
              name: "ACF2",
              children: [
                {
                  name: "ACFG1",
                  children: []
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              name: "ACF3",
              children: [
                {
                  name: "ACFH1",
                  children: []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

findTreeNodeAndPath("name", "ACFG1", "children", exampleData);
console.log(nodePath.value)
```

The recursive part of the code will iterate on the children of the current node. The existing strategy here is depending on the `nodePath.value` having at least one element, which indicates that it found the targetted node. Later on, it'll skip the remaining nodes and would break out of recursion.

The `nodePath.value` variable will give you the node-to-root path.