# modify json in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = {Sheets: {'data': worksheet}, SheetNames: ['data']};
    XLSX.writeFile(workbook, ExcelService.toExportFileName(excelFileName));
  }

exportToExcel() {
  this.accountCreationService.getExcelDataForExport().subscribe((response)=>{
    if(response!=null && response.CaseList!=null && response.CaseList.length>0)
    this.excelService.exportAsExcelFile(response.CaseList, 'TestData');
    else
    console.log('ERROR Fetching Excel Data From API')
  },(error)=>{
    console.log('ERROR : unable to export to EXCEL : ' + error);
  })
  }
```

My requirement was to export the data I'm getting from an API to an excel sheet.

```
Response Payload:

{
      "pyStatusWork": "New",
      "LegalCompanyName": "",
      "EnablePend": null,
      "DisplayId": "",
      "IsLocked": false,
      "taxExemptJurisdictionValue": "",
      "pzInsKey": "",
      "Origination": {
        "BatchID": ""
      },
      "Source": "",
      "AccountMaintenance": {
        "AccountStatus": {
          "RequestorType": "",
          "RequestSource": "",
          "CodeStatus": ""
        },
        "TaskType": "",
        "modifiedByUserId": ""
      }
    }
```

Like this I'm getting 100's of records, the first issue is, If I export the same payload as it is to the excel sheet I'm not able to see the data under `accountmaintenacne {}` and `Origination {}` objects in the spreadsheet.

Second issue, I want to see different key ("key":"value") names in the spreadsheet.

Comment: I don't understand. what is your question?

Comment: How do I modify objects inside a JSON object ?? I want to convert the above JSON object to like this.

{
      "pyStatusWork": "New",
      "LegalCompanyName": "",
      "EnablePend": null,
      "DisplayId": "",
      "IsLocked": false,
      "taxExemptJurisdictionValue": "",
      "pzInsKey": "",
      "BatchID": "",
      "Source": "",
       "RequestorType": "",
       "RequestSource": "",
       "CodeStatus": ""
       "TaskType": "",
       "modifiedByUserId": ""
      }
    }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to flatten / un-flatten nested JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098797/fastest-way-to-flatten-un-flatten-nested-json-objects)

Comment: `var obj = JSON.parse(rawJSONString); obj.myProperty = 'my value';`?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new function to reformat json object into a simple object key:value

Like this :

```
const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(myCustomFunction(json));

myCustomFunction(json:any[]){
    let newJson:any[];

    angular.forEach(json, function(item) {
        newJson.push({
            "pyStatusWork": item.pyStatusWork,
            "LegalCompanyName": item.LegalCompanyName,
            "EnablePend": item.EnablePend,
            "DisplayId": item.DisplayId,
            "IsLocked": item.IsLocked,
            "taxExemptJurisdictionValue": item.taxExemptJurisdictionValue,
            "pzInsKey": item.pzInsKey,
            "Origination.BatchID": item.Origination.BatchID,
            "Source": item.Source,
            "AccountMaintenance.AccountStatus.RequestorType": item.AccountMaintenance.AccountStatus.RequestorType,
            "AccountMaintenance.AccountStatus.RequestSource": item.AccountMaintenance.AccountStatus.RequestSource,
            "AccountMaintenance.AccountStatus.CodeStatus": item.AccountMaintenance.AccountStatus.CodeStatus,
            "TaskType": item.TaskType,
            "modifiedByUserId": item.modifiedByUserId
            }
        });
    });
    return newJson;
}
```

This should work if the object fields was statics.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Alwan for your quick response, will try this