# How to Bind to Variable Length Property in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table which is going to display results sent from the server, however the results themselves have a dynamic shape.  There is also another API which provides the shape / schema of the nesting.  So my HTML looks something like this:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="result in results">
     <td ng-repeat="path in schema.paths">{{result[path]}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Of course, this does not work since `path` may be one item, or it may be many items expressed as a dotted string.  That is, path could be `nesting1` which would work, or it could be `nesting1.nesting2.nesting3` which would not work.  How can I accommodate this use case without using the `$compile` service in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this question correctly, I think there is a Lodash function that can help you here.

It's called [get](https://lodash.com/docs/#get). Usage:

```
var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };

_.get(object, 'a[0].b.c');
// => 3

_.get(object, ['a', '0', 'b', 'c']);
// => 3

_.get(object, 'a.b.c', 'default');
// => 'default'
```

For your case it might look something like:

**controller.js**

```
import { get } from 'lodash-es';

...

// Your controller code...

...

    this.getResultAtPath = path => get(this.results, path);
```

**template.html**

```
<tr ng-repeat="result in results">
     <td ng-repeat="path in schema.paths">{{ getResultAtPath(path) }}</td>
</tr>
```

If you don't want to take on the dependency, I suggest you take a look at their implementation for [`get`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.11/lodash.js#L13127).

Comment: Great thank you, I rolled my one as a basic map walk along the lines of:  function getNestedMapItem(path, data) {
    var pointer = data
    for(var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
        var item = path[i]
        pointer = pointer[item]
    }
    return pointer
}

Comment: @mobiusinversion nice :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, `get` function should work.
Alternatively you could flatten your 'result'.
For example if there is an object:
`{'a': {'b': 3}}`
then flattened it would look like so:
`{'a.b': 3}`

There are lots of implementations posted here, for example:
[flatten nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098797/fastest-way-to-flatten-un-flatten-nested-json-objects)