# Flattening JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to flatten multi level JSON object to simple output.

```
key2:{  
   keyB1:{  
      keyC1:{  
         keyD1:'value b c 1'
      }
   },
   keyB2:{  
      keyC2:'value b c 2'
   }
}
```

My output is fine in the first iteration, but the second time, the counter is not getting set. Kindly, run the code to see the problem.

```
function flattenInput(datainput) {
    const result = {};

    const callit1 = function(keylist, datainput) {
        for (i in datainput) {
            keylist = keylist + '.' + i;
            if (typeof datainput[i] === 'object') {
                return callit1(keylist, datainput[i]);
            } else {
                return keylist;
            }
        }
    }

    let klist = '';
    for (i in datainput) {
        if (typeof datainput[i] === 'object') {
            klist = callit1(i, datainput[i]);
            console.log(klist);
        }
    }
    console.log(result);
}

flattenInput(input);
```

### Expected:

> key2.keyB1.keyC1.keyD1: 'value b c 1'
>
> key2.keyB2.keyC2: 'value b c 2'

### What I get:

> **key2.keyB1.keyC1.keyD1: 'value b c 1'**
> (only)

Comment: json is malformatted

Comment: I think using let i instead of jsut i should do the trick otherwise they are using the same variable probably interfering with each other

Comment: Seems like this is a duplicate. See [fastest-way-to-flatten-un-flatten-nested-json-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098797/fastest-way-to-flatten-un-flatten-nested-json-objects). You can pick one of solutions and adapt it to get the exact format you fancy.

Comment: You increase the "keylist" each iteration in the callit1. The current code would give `key2.keyB1.keyB2.keyC2` for the second key. You need a different variable to store the "keylist" for the actual item or do `callit1(keylist + "." + i, datainput[i])` instead of overriding the original value. Otherwise the code looks ok. I guess it is part of an untested spaghetti code. I would check the console for errors.

Comment: Is this something you're trying to figure out on your own or can you just use the flat npm module?

Comment: Added jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/mhqtxv9k/

Comment: Yes, I have to do it on my own, cannot use the flat module. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion in order to go deeper thru the keys, and an array of keys for keeping the track of visited keys.

*This is assuming the deepest object is a string.*

```js
let obj = {   key2: {     keyB1: {       keyC1: {         keyD1: 'value b c 1'       }     },     keyB2: {       keyC2: 'value b c 2'     }   } };

function downstream(desiredObj, currentObj, keys) {
  if (typeof currentObj === 'string') {
    desiredObj[keys.join('.')] = currentObj;
  } else {
    Object.keys(currentObj).forEach(key => downstream(desiredObj, currentObj[key], [...keys, key]));
  }
}

let result = {};
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => downstream(result, obj[key], [key]));

console.log(result);
```