# I want to change API response JSON format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native

Here is actual response I got from API, I want to convert the below JSON format

From:

```
"data": [
    [
      {
        "isFile": "true",
        "fileType": "image",
        "filesize": 100793,
        "filename": "attachment_0.png",
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "isFile": "true",
        "fileType": "image",
        "filesize": 6343078,
        "filename": "attachment_1.png"
      }
    ]
  ]
```

To:

```
"data": [
      {
        "isFile": "true",
        "fileType": "image",
        "filesize": 100793,
        "filename": "attachment_0.png",
      },
      {
        "isFile": "true",
        "fileType": "image",
        "filesize": 6343078,
        "filename": "attachment_1.png"
      }
  ]
```

How do I remove the array between the Object.

Comment: Parse it first and then you could use `flat` on data?

Comment: Your JSON is not valid. `"filename": "attachment_0.png",` is wrong. The comma is not allowed. `"data":` is also wrong. You can`t start with a property.

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert JSON to JavaScript
2. Flatten the array
3. Convert JavaScript to Json

```
const json = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data).flat())
```

I had to fix your JSON:

```js
const data = `[
    [
      {
        "isFile": "true",
        "fileType": "image",
        "filesize": 100793,
        "filename": "attachment_0.png"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "isFile": "true",
        "fileType": "image",
        "filesize": 6343078,
        "filename": "attachment_1.png"
      }
    ]
  ]`
  
const json = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data).flat());
console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything you want is in the first element of the `data` array, so just index it.

```
obj = JSON.parse(response);
obj.data = obj.data[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If the response is never really big you can always do

```
let data = JSON.parse(response);
for (el in data) {
    el = el[0]
}
```

otherwise, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098797/fastest-way-to-flatten-un-flatten-nested-json-objects)