# Convert sparse object to nested object

Tags: javascript, object

I need to format this JavaScript object to the output format. Any help please?

```js
let values = {
  'ban_Name': "test",
  'bank': "yes",
  'cont_1-counterName': "Cname1",
  'cont_1-obl': "obl1",
  'cont_1-orig': "orig 1",
  'cont_2-counterName': "Cname2",
  'cont_2-obl': "obl2",
  'cont_2-orig': "orig 2",
  'cont': "yes",
  'creditors': "no",
}
```

Output should be

```js
{
  'ban_Name': "test",
  'bank': "yes",
  'cont': "yes",
  'conts' [{
    'counterName': "Cname1",
    'cobl': "obl1",
    'orig': "orig 1",
  }, {
    'counterName': "Cname2",
    'obl': "obl2",
    'orig': "orig 2",
  }],
  'creditors': "no",
}
```

Can some one suggest me a way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Could you provide any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try converting the values to a list of key value pairs that look closer to JavaScript nested paths:

| Key Path | Value |
| --- | --- |
| ban_Name | test |
| bank | yes |
| conts[0].counterName | Cname1 |
| conts[0].obl | obl1 |
| conts[0].orig | orig 1 |
| conts[1].counterName | Cname2 |
| conts[1].obl | obl2 |
| conts[1].orig | orig 2 |
| cont | yes |
| creditors | no |

Note that the assignment of `"yes"` to `cont` will replace the array that you have defined above, so I altered the replacer to add an "s" before the array index bracket notation.

```js
key.replace(/_(\d)-/g, (g0, g1) => `s[${g1 - 1}].`);
```

### Simple solution

This solution is very simple, because it fails if you have more than two levels deep. If you need something that would work better, try to find a recursive way to convert key paths to a nested object.

```js
let values = {
  'ban_Name': "test",
  'bank': "yes",
  'cont_1-counterName': "Cname1",
  'cont_1-obl': "obl1",
  'cont_1-orig': "orig 1",
  'cont_2-counterName': "Cname2",
  'cont_2-obl': "obl2",
  'cont_2-orig': "orig 2",
  'cont': "yes",
  'creditors': "no",
};

const pairs = Object.entries(values).map(([key, val]) =>
  [key.replace(/_(\d)-/g, (g0, g1) => `s[${g1 - 1}].`), val]);

console.log(pairs.map(([key, val]) => `${key} => ${val}`).join('\n'));

const toObject = (pairs, acc = {}) => {
  pairs.forEach(([key, val]) => {
    const [headKey, ...tailKeys] = key.split(/\./g);
    if (tailKeys.length === 0) {
      acc[headKey] = val;
    } else {
      const [otherKey] = tailKeys;
      const [match, arrKey, arrIndex] = headKey.match(/(\w+)\[(\d+)\]/);
      if (match) {
        const index = parseInt(arrIndex, 10);
        acc[arrKey] = (acc[arrKey] || []);
        acc[arrKey][index] = (acc[arrKey][index] || {});
        acc[arrKey][index][otherKey] = val;
      }
    }
  });
  return acc;
};

console.log(toObject(pairs));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

### Dynamic alternative

The following will work for even deeper nesting.

```js
// See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19101235/1762224
Object.unflatten = function(data) {
  if (Object(data) !== data || Array.isArray(data)) return data;
  const regex = /\.?([^.\[\]]+)|\[(\d+)(\])?/g, resultholder = {};
  for (let p in data) {
    let scope = resultholder, prop = '', m;
    while (m = regex.exec(p)) {
      scope = scope[prop] || (scope[prop] = (m[2] ? [] : {}));
      prop = m[2] || m[1];
    }
    scope[prop] = data[p];
  }
  return resultholder[''] || resultholder;
};

const fixKeys = (obj, keyFn) => Object.entries(obj)
  .reduce((acc, [key, val]) => ({ ...acc, [keyFn(key)]: val }), {});

// =====================  Main  =====================

const values = {
  'ban_Name': "test",
  'bank': "yes",
  'cont_1-counterName': "Cname1",
  'cont_1-obl': "obl1",
  'cont_1-orig': "orig 1",
  'cont_2-counterName': "Cname2",
  'cont_2-obl': "obl2",
  'cont_2-orig': "orig 2",
  'cont': "yes",
  'creditors': "no",
};

const fixed = fixKeys(values, key =>
  key.replace(/_(\d)-/g, (g0, g1) => `s[${g1 - 1}].`));

console.log(Object.unflatten(fixed));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let values = {
    'ban_Name': "test",
    'bank': "yes",
    'cont_1-counterName': "Cname1",
    'cont_1-obl': "obl1",
    'cont_1-orig': "orig 1",
    'cont_2-counterName': "Cname2",
    'cont_2-obl': "obl2",
    'cont_2-orig': "orig 2",
    'cont': "yes",
    'creditors': "no",
}

let output = {}
let contsArray = []

const regex = /cont_(\d+)-(\w+)/gm;
for (let key in values) {
    let m = '';
    if (key.startsWith('cont_')) {
        while ((m = regex.exec(key)) !== null) {
            // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
            if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
                regex.lastIndex++;
            }
            let contIndex = m[1]

            if (!contsArray[contIndex - 1]) {
                contsArray[contIndex - 1] = {}
            }
            contsArray[contIndex - 1][m[2]] = values[key]

        }
    } else {
        output[key] = values[key]
    }
}
output.conts = contsArray
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function objChange(objTemp) {
   keyArr = Object.keys(objTemp);
   let obj = {};
   obj['conts'] = [];
   let consone = {};
   let constwo= {};
   for(let i of keyArr){   
      if(i.includes("cont_1-")) {
         const name = i.replace("cont_1-",'');
          consone[name] = values[i];
      } else if (i.includes("cont_2-")){ 
         const name = i.replace("cont_2-",'');
          constwo[name] = values[i];       
      } else {

        obj[i] = values[i]
      }
    }
    Object.keys(consone).length ? obj['conts'].push(consone) : '';
    Object.keys(constwo).length ? obj['conts'].push(constwo) : '';
    return obj;
}
let values = {
  'ban_Name': "test",
  'bank': "yes",
  'cont_1-counterName': "Cname1",
  'cont_1-obl': "obl1",
  'cont_1-orig': "orig 1",
  'cont_2-counterName': "Cname2",
  'cont_2-obl': "obl2",
  'cont_2-orig': "orig 2",
  'cont': "yes",
  'creditors': "no",
}
objChange(values)
```

P.s - I know this on **Not fully optimize**. but i am low in time show if you want to make more optimize then you can.Thanks you

Comment: the big problem with this is the hardcoding of `cont_1` and `cont_2`.  I assumed that these were dynamic and we needed to handle `cont_42` or any other such nodes

Comment: Yes they are dynamic, So hard coding will not work. Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

This works by converting our object into a format like this:

```js
[
  [["ban_Name"], "test"],
  [["bank"], "yes"],
  [["conts", 0, "counterName"], "Cname1"],
  [["conts", 0, "obl"], "obl1"],
  [["conts", 0, "orig"], "orig 1"], 
  [["conts", 1, "counterName"], "Cname2"],
  [["conts", 1, "obl"], "obl2"],
  [["conts", 1, "orig"], "orig 2"],
  [["cont"], "yes"],
  [["creditors"], "no"]
]
```

and then using a generic `hydrate` function that takes an array of path-value pairs like this and puts them together into an object:

```js
// utility functions
const setPath = ([p, ...ps]) => (v) => (o) =>
  p == undefined ? v : Object .assign (
    Array .isArray (o) || Number.isInteger (p) ? [] : {},
    {...o, [p]: setPath (ps) (v) ((o || {}) [p])}
  )

const hydrate = (xs) =>
  xs .reduce ((a, [p, v]) => setPath (p) (v) (a), {})


// helper function
const makePath = (k, parts = k .match (/^cont_(\d+)\-(.+)$/)) => 
  parts ? ['conts', parts [1] - 1, parts [2]] : [k]


// main function
const convert = (input) =>
  hydrate (Object .entries (input) .map (([k, v]) => [makePath (k), v]))


// sample data
const values  = {'ban_Name': "test", 'bank': "yes", 'cont_1-counterName': "Cname1", 'cont_1-obl': "obl1", 'cont_1-orig': "orig 1", 'cont_2-counterName': "Cname2", 'cont_2-obl': "obl2", 'cont_2-orig': "orig 2", 'cont': "yes", 'creditors': "no"}


// demo
console .log (convert (values))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

**`setPath`** is a generic utility function that takes a path like `['a', 'b', 'c']`, a value like 42, and an object like `{a: {b: {d: 1}}, e: 2}` and adds the value along that path to (a copy of) that object, yielding something like `{a: {b: {c: 42, d: 1}}, e: 2}`.

**`hydrate`** is similar to `Object .fromEntries` except that it uses a path rather than a key, so can build nested objects from a flat list.

We have the helper function `makePath` which takes a plain key like `'bank'` and returns `['bank']` or takes one of your formatted keys like `'cont_2-orig'` and returns `['conts', 2, 'orig']`.

Then our main function simply needs to map over the entries in the input object, converting the keys with `makePath`, then hydrate an object with the resulting array.

Note that `hydrate` and `setPath` are genuinely reusable functions that you might want in multiple parts of your application, and so probably belong in some sort of utility library.  The only custom code here is `makePath` and `convert`, and those are quite simple.