# How to map object in React

Tags: json, reactjs, dictionary, object

I have an JSON object that I am trying to map. SO basically the JSON is like this:

```
{
  "Status": true, 
  "discounts": {
    "broker": {
      "discount": "1"
    }, 
    "dealer": {
      "discount": "0.7"
    }, 
    "individual": {
      "number_of_cars_discount": {
        "1": "1", 
        "10": "1", 
        "2": "0.98", 
        "3": "1", 
        "4": "1", 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So I set the post and fetch the data.

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const res = await Axios({
        });
        if (res.status == 200) {
          setPosts(res.data);
        }
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err.message);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);
```

So to get the value and display it inside the table here is my code:

```
<tbody>
                    <td>
                  {Object.keys(posts).map((post, index) => (
                    <tr>
                      <div key={`broker-${index}`}>{post.discounts}</div>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </td>
                  </tbody>
```

But unfortunately, I am getting nothing.
Thanks for your helps...

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `posts` with empty array not boolean value:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
```

And you have to map on `posts` directly. So, you don't need to use `Object.keys()`.

Comment: I actually set it like this const [posts, setPosts] = useState({}); but could you please explain the second thing?

Comment: Because I am getting Cannot convert undefined or null to object if I do like this {Object.keys().map((key) => (
                        <tr>
                          <div key={key}>{posts.discounts.broker[key]}</div>
                        </tr>
                      ))}

Answer (score 0):

You can keep `posts` as an empty `Object` when you do `useState()`.

The nested JSON object that you have doesn't work with those cycling you are trying.
If you `console.log` the `key` in your arrow function inside the `map` you would discover that it would be changing value between "Status" and "discounts", so with those keys you cannot access the object inside `posts.discounts.broker` because those properties don't exist.

`posts.discounts.broker.Status` and `posts.discounts.broker.discounts` will always return `undefined`.

I think you should consider whether you should [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098797/fastest-way-to-flatten-un-flatten-nested-json-objects) your nested `JSON` or, if you just need what's inside `discounts.broker`, then you can set just that `Object` inside of `posts`.

Comment: You mean I use set diffetent useState for each dealer, individual etc?

Comment: So, do you need to use those other `discounts` properties?

Comment: Yes I do for all of them

Comment: I guess your only way here to not overcomplicate the rendering, since you know the properties you need, is to, as you asked, save every "`sub-object`" in a separate variable.

So you will have:
`const [broker, setBroker] = useState({})`
Same thing for `individual` and `dealer`.
Once you fill them, then you can render them by accessing the properties directly.
For `individual` you can cycle through the `Object` by accessing the property `number_of_cars_discounts` and do an `Object.keys(individual.number_of_cars_discounts)`, so you can retrieve every value inside that object too