# Collect all paths in JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, path

I'm dealing with the following JavaScript object:

```
{
    "gender": "man",
    "jobinfo": {
        "type": "teacher"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Daniel",
            "age": 12,
            "pets": [
                {
                    "type": "cat", 
                    "name": "Willy",
                    "age": 2
                },
                {
                    "type": "dog", 
                    "name": "Jimmie",
                    "age": 5
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to print out each of the paths (keys and array indices) within the object, including the parents (i.e. `children` should be printed as should everything in it).

```
gender
jobinfo,
jobinfo.type,
children,
children.0.name,
children.0.age,
children.0.pets,
children.0.pets.0.type,
children.0.pets.0.name,
children.0.pets.0.age,
children.0.pets.1.type,
children.0.pets.1.name,
children.0.pets.1.age
```

I tried this code with modifications but it didnt work for me:

```
function getPath(object) {
    for (key in object) {
        if (Array.isArray(object[key]) === true) {
            console.log(key)
            getPath(object[key])
        } else if (typeof object[key] === 'object') {
            console.log(key)
            getPath(object[key])
        } else {
            console.log(key)
        }
    }
}
```

It's printing all keys in the JSON, but I'm struggling with joining the paths, especially in nested elements.

Comment: I believe you are looking for a flattening function. I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19101235/5501292) may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this version array keys that are consisted of numbers like 'children.0' and so on handled and this gives the result exactly what you wanted:

```js
const json = {"gender":"man","jobinfo":{"type":"teacher"},"children":[{"name":"Daniel","age":12,"pets":[{"type":"cat","name":"Willy","age":2},{"type":"dog","name":"Jimmie","age":5}]}]};

function getPath(object, previousPath) {
  for (key in object) {
    let currentPath = previousPath ? `${previousPath}.${key}` : key

    if (Array.isArray(object[key])) {
      console.log(currentPath)
      getPath(object[key], currentPath)
    } else if (typeof object[key] === 'object') {
      if (!Array.isArray(object)) { // skipping logging array keys like children.0
        console.log(currentPath)
      }
      getPath(object[key], currentPath)
    } else {
      console.log(currentPath)
    }
  }
}

getPath(json)
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```js
const data = {"gender":"man","jobinfo":{"type":"teacher"},"children":[{"name":"Daniel","age":12,"pets":[{"type":"cat","name":"Willy","age":2},{"type":"dog","name":"Jimmie","age":5}]}]};

const getPath = (currPath, item) => {
  console.log(currPath);
  if (Array.isArray(item)) {
    item.forEach((el, idx) => getPath(`${currPath}.${idx}`, el));
  } else if (typeof item == "object") {
    Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      getPath(`${currPath}.${key}`, value);
    });
  }
};

Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  getPath(key, value);
});
```

Basically I just loop through each of the entries in the initial object, using the key as the path at that stage and checking if the value is an object or array. I always print the path within the function (to provide the outer layers you want) and then I recurse over the inner layers, adding to the path as needed.