# Write a function that converts an object of any nesting into a string (Recursion) JS

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a simple object:

```
   let obj = {
      season: 'winter',
      data: {
          month: ['December', 'January', 'February']
         }
    };
```

I need to get a string like:

```
`season=winter&data[month][0]=December&data[month][1]=January&data[month][2]=February`
```

I tried but I didn't completely succeed

```
  function convertToText(obj) {
   let string = [];
   if (typeof(obj) == "object") {
        for (prop in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            string.push(prop + "=" + convertToText(obj[prop]));
        };
    return string.join("&");
    } else {
        string.push(JSON.stringify(obj))
    }

    return string.join();
}
```

and gets this:

```
"season='winter'&data=month=0='December'&1='January'&2='February'"
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19098797/1048572) help? If not, please show us your attempt, or explain where exactly you are stuck at writing this function.

Comment: [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) could also be helpful

Comment: Voted to reopen, as the edits make this a reasonable question, and there is clearly an honest attempt provided.

Comment: Question seems good but how deep can the nesting be?