# convert json object to csv

Tags: java, json, export-to-csv

I need to convert a complex .json file in a csv in a java evironment.
I've already seen it 
[Javascript / convert json to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381539/javascript-convert-json-to-csv)
and [Converting JSON to XLS/CSV in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172158/converting-json-to-xls-csv-in-java) and [Convert JSON format to CSV format for MS Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130849/convert-json-format-to-csv-format-for-ms-excel) and the applications developed in it, but they didn't work with my file, that is like this example:

```
{
    "metadata": {"result_type": "recent", "iso_language_code": "it"}, 
    "created_at": "Thu Apr 04 16: 48: 29 +0000 2013", 
    "user": {
        "id": "integer", 
        "id_str": "id_str", 
        "name": "a name and a surname", 
        "screen_name": "ascreenname", 
        "location": "Roma", 
        "description": "some description ", 
        "url": "some url", 
        "entities": {
            "url": {
                "urls": [{
                    "url": "other url", 
                    "expanded_url": null, 
                    "indices": [0, 39]
                }]
            }, 
            "description": {"urls": []}
        }, 
        "notifications": null
    }, 
    "geo": null, 
    "coordinates": null, 
    "place": null, 
    "contributors": null, 
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [
            {"text": "text", "indices": [29, 35]}, 
            {"text": "text", "indices": [36, 52]}, 
            {"text": "roma", "indices": [53, 58]}, 
            {"text": "ostiense", "indices": [59, 68]}, 
            {"text": "text", "indices": [69, 79]}, 
            {"text": "text", "indices": [80, 92]}, 
            {"text": "text", "indices": [93, 99]}
        ], 
        "urls": [
            {"url": "an url", "expanded_url": "an url", "indices": [101, 123]}
        ], 
        "user_mentions": []
    }, 
    "lang": "it"
}
```

Comment: Those questions you reference should be enough to solve your  particular problem, with some customization. If you fail your customization effort, then show us the code for more help.

Comment: json data structure you have given is not directly mappable to csv.  You may have to parse and construct a suitable object graph and then write back a csv, say using openCSV.

Comment: Don't post a wall of code as an answer. Edit your answer instead, and only include relevant sections of the code. Nobody wants to read through a ton of code to figure out where your problem is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert java Object to CSV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791353/convert-java-object-to-csv)

Comment: CSV is intended for flat rows of data, not for structured data. You need to figure out how to flatten your JSON object into a single row of values.