# How can I convert data from json into csv file using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, csv

I have data in json format like :

```
{
    "key" : "Quantity" ,
    "bar": true,
    "values" : [ [ '2012-06-26' , 1271000.0] , [ 1138683600000 , 1271000.0] , [ 1141102800000 , 1271000.0] , [ 1143781200000 , 0] , [ 1146369600000 , 0] , [ 1149048000000 , 0] , [ 1151640000000 , 0] , [ 1154318400000 , 0] , [ 1156996800000 , 0] , [ 1159588800000 , 3899486.0] , [ 1162270800000 , 3899486.0] , [ 1164862800000 , 3899486.0] , [ 1167541200000 , 3564700.0] , [ 1170219600000 , 3564700.0] , [ 1172638800000 , 3564700.0] , [ 1175313600000 , 2648493.0] , [ 1177905600000 , 2648493.0] , [ 1180584000000 , 2648493.0] , [ 1183176000000 , 2522993.0] , [ 1185854400000 , 2522993.0] , [ 1188532800000 , 2522993.0] , [ 1191124800000 , 2906501.0] , [ 1193803200000 , 2906501.0] , [ 1196398800000 , 2906501.0] , [ 1199077200000 , 2206761.0] , [ 1201755600000 , 2206761.0] , [ 1204261200000 , 2206761.0] , [ 1206936000000 , 2287726.0] , [ 1209528000000 , 2287726.0] , [ 1212206400000 , 2287726.0] , [ 1214798400000 , 2732646.0] , [ 1217476800000 , 2732646.0] , [ 1220155200000 , 2732646.0] , [ 1222747200000 , 2599196.0] , [ 1225425600000 , 2599196.0] , [ 1228021200000 , 2599196.0] , [ 1230699600000 , 1924387.0] , [ 1233378000000 , 1924387.0] , [ 1235797200000 , 1924387.0] , [ 1238472000000 , 1756311.0] , [ 1241064000000 , 1756311.0] , [ 1243742400000 , 1756311.0] , [ 1246334400000 , 1743470.0] , [ 1249012800000 , 1743470.0] , [ 1251691200000 , 1743470.0] , [ 1254283200000 , 1519010.0] , [ 1256961600000 , 1519010.0] , [ 1259557200000 , 1519010.0] , [ 1262235600000 , 1591444.0] , [ 1264914000000 , 1591444.0] , [ 1267333200000 , 1591444.0] , [ 1270008000000 , 1543784.0] , [ 1272600000000 , 1543784.0] , [ 1275278400000 , 1543784.0] , [ 1277870400000 , 1309915.0] , [ 1280548800000 , 1309915.0] , [ 1283227200000 , 1309915.0] , [ 1285819200000 , 1331875.0] , [ 1288497600000 , 1331875.0] , [ 1291093200000 , 1331875.0] , [ 1293771600000 , 1331875.0] , [ 1296450000000 , 1154695.0] , [ 1298869200000 , 1154695.0] , [ 1301544000000 , 1194025.0] , [ 1304136000000 , 1194025.0] , [ 1306814400000 , 1194025.0] , [ 1309406400000 , 1194025.0] , [ 1312084800000 , 1194025.0] , [ 1314763200000 , 1244525.0] , [ 1317355200000 , 475000.0] , [ 1320033600000 , 475000.0] , [ 1322629200000 , 475000.0] , [ 1325307600000 , 690033.0] , [ 1327986000000 , 690033.0] , [ 1330491600000 , 690033.0] , [ 1333166400000 , 514733.0] , [ 1335758400000 , 514733.0]]
  },
  {
    "key" : "Price" ,
    "color" : "#FF0000",
    "values" : [ [ '2012-06-26' , 71.89] , [ 1138683600000 , 75.51] , [ 1141102800000 , 68.49] , [ 1143781200000 , 62.72] , [ 1146369600000 , 70.39] , [ 1149048000000 , 59.77] , [ 1151640000000 , 57.27] , [ 1154318400000 , 67.96] , [ 1156996800000 , 67.85] , [ 1159588800000 , 76.98] , [ 1162270800000 , 81.08] , [ 1164862800000 , 91.66] , [ 1167541200000 , 84.84] , [ 1170219600000 , 85.73] , [ 1172638800000 , 84.61] , [ 1175313600000 , 92.91] , [ 1177905600000 , 99.8] , [ 1180584000000 , 121.191] , [ 1183176000000 , 122.04] , [ 1185854400000 , 131.76] , [ 1188532800000 , 138.48] , [ 1191124800000 , 153.47] , [ 1193803200000 , 189.95] , [ 1196398800000 , 182.22] , [ 1199077200000 , 198.08] , [ 1201755600000 , 135.36] , [ 1204261200000 , 125.02] , [ 1206936000000 , 143.5] , [ 1209528000000 , 173.95] , [ 1212206400000 , 188.75] , [ 1214798400000 , 167.44] , [ 1217476800000 , 158.95] , [ 1220155200000 , 169.53] , [ 1222747200000 , 113.66] , [ 1225425600000 , 107.59] , [ 1228021200000 , 92.67] , [ 1230699600000 , 85.35] , [ 1233378000000 , 90.13] , [ 1235797200000 , 89.31] , [ 1238472000000 , 105.12] , [ 1241064000000 , 125.83] , [ 1243742400000 , 135.81] , [ 1246334400000 , 142.43] , [ 1249012800000 , 163.39] , [ 1251691200000 , 168.21] , [ 1254283200000 , 185.35] , [ 1256961600000 , 188.5] , [ 1259557200000 , 199.91] , [ 1262235600000 , 210.732] , [ 1264914000000 , 192.063] , [ 1267333200000 , 204.62] , [ 1270008000000 , 235.0] , [ 1272600000000 , 261.09] , [ 1275278400000 , 256.88] , [ 1277870400000 , 251.53] , [ 1280548800000 , 257.25] , [ 1283227200000 , 243.1] , [ 1285819200000 , 283.75] , [ 1288497600000 , 300.98] , [ 1291093200000 , 311.15] , [ 1293771600000 , 322.56] , [ 1296450000000 , 339.32] , [ 1298869200000 , 353.21] , [ 1301544000000 , 348.5075] , [ 1304136000000 , 350.13] , [ 1306814400000 , 347.83] , [ 1309406400000 , 335.67] , [ 1312084800000 , 390.48] , [ 1314763200000 , 384.83] , [ 1317355200000 , 381.32] , [ 1320033600000 , 404.78] , [ 1322629200000 , 382.2] , [ 1325307600000 , 405.0] , [ 1327986000000 , 456.48] , [ 1330491600000 , 542.44] , [ 1333166400000 , 599.55] , [ 1335758400000 , 583.98] ]
  },
  {
    "key" : "Line Chart2",
    "color" : "#2F4F4F",
    "values" : [ [ '2012-06-26' , 91.89] , [ 1138683600000 , 95.51] , [ 1141102800000 , 88.49] , [ 1143781200000 , 82.72] , [ 1146369600000 , 90.39] , [ 1149048000000 , 79.77] , [ 1151640000000 , 87.27] , [ 1154318400000 , 97.96] , [ 1156996800000 , 97.85] , [ 1159588800000 , 106.98] , [ 1162270800000 , 111.08] , [ 1164862800000 , 121.66] , [ 1167541200000 , 114.84] , [ 1170219600000 , 115.73] , [ 1172638800000 , 114.61] , [ 1175313600000 , 122.91] , [ 1177905600000 , 129.8] , [ 1180584000000 , 151.191] , [ 1183176000000 , 152.04] , [ 1185854400000 , 161.76] , [ 1188532800000 , 168.48] , [ 1191124800000 , 183.47] , [ 1193803200000 , 219.95] , [ 1196398800000 , 212.22] , [ 1199077200000 , 228.08] , [ 1201755600000 , 155.36] , [ 1204261200000 , 155.02] , [ 1206936000000 , 173.5] , [ 1209528000000 , 203.95] , [ 1212206400000 , 218.75] , [ 1214798400000 , 197.44] , [ 1217476800000 , 188.95] , [ 1220155200000 , 199.53] , [ 1222747200000 , 143.66] , [ 1225425600000 , 137.59] , [ 1228021200000 , 122.67] , [ 1230699600000 , 115.35] , [ 1233378000000 , 120.13] , [ 1235797200000 , 119.31] , [ 1238472000000 , 135.12] , [ 1241064000000 , 155.83] , [ 1243742400000 , 165.81] , [ 1246334400000 , 172.43] , [ 1249012800000 , 193.39] , [ 1251691200000 , 198.21] , [ 1254283200000 , 215.35] , [ 1256961600000 , 218.5] , [ 1259557200000 , 229.91] , [ 1262235600000 , 240.732] , [ 1264914000000 , 222.063] , [ 1267333200000 , 234.62] , [ 1270008000000 , 265.0] , [ 1272600000000 , 291.09] , [ 1275278400000 , 286.88] , [ 1277870400000 , 281.53] , [ 1280548800000 , 287.25] , [ 1283227200000 , 273.1] , [ 1285819200000 , 313.75] , [ 1288497600000 , 303.98] , [ 1291093200000 , 314.15] , [ 1293771600000 , 325.56] , [ 1296450000000 , 342.32] , [ 1298869200000 , 356.21] , [ 1301544000000 , 351.5075] , [ 1304136000000 , 353.13] , [ 1306814400000 , 350.83] , [ 1309406400000 , 338.67] , [ 1312084800000 , 393.48] , [ 1314763200000 , 387.83] , [ 1317355200000 , 384.32] , [ 1320033600000 , 407.78] , [ 1322629200000 , 385.2] , [ 1325307600000 , 408.0] , [ 1327986000000 , 459.48] , [ 1330491600000 , 545.44] , [ 1333166400000 , 562.55] , [ 1335758400000 , 586.98] ]
}
```

I have tried using [json-csv.com](https://json-csv.com) to convert my data json, the result is in [here](https://json-csv.com/result.aspx?id=8f0250d0-b434-419b-9efd-f68dbe1164aa)

I want to make it using javascript, I have tried using javascript, in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZVLJ/4/), but in csv file not same what I want, want same like in [here](https://json-csv.com/result.aspx?id=8f0250d0-b434-419b-9efd-f68dbe1164aa), how I can do that ?

Comment: try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847766/how-to-convert-json-to-csv-format-and-store-in-a-variable

Comment: i have tried it too, but still incorrect :(