# exporting large number of rows from datatables to excel

Tags: php, jquery, excel, datatables

I am using datatables jQuery plugin for data rendering and exporting[image]

I am trying to export a large number of rows from datatables to an excel file, but the browser crashes.

I have tried on Chrome and Firefox, both crash when I export excel or csv.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you using serverside datatable or browser level?

Comment: Coz it must nbe taking longer time

Comment: yes, I retrieve data using ajax/php

Comment: the problem is not with data retrieving, it's after data retrieving, just when I export it.

Comment: take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009295/how-to-export-large-amount-of-json-data-to-csv-without-browser-crash) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23301467/javascript-exporting-large-text-csv-file-crashes-google-chrome)

Comment: @dot.Py, I am using datatables.

Comment: @CairoCoder What happens when you export as PDF?

Comment: @KinshukLahiri, didn't give it a try !

Comment: @CairoCoder give it a try. And when you click on export for csv or excel, Is there any error in console?

Comment: @KinshukLahiri, no error !

Comment: @KinshukLahiri, same thing for PDF!